# How to display all the dates between two given dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, gaps-and-islands

Using SQL server 2000. If the Start date is `06/23/2008` and End date is `06/30/2008`

Then I need the Output of query as

```
06/23/2008
06/24/2008
06/25/2008
.
.
.
06/30/2008
```

I Created a Table names as Integer which has 1 Column, column values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 then I used the below mentioned query

Tried Query

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, H.i * 100 + T .i * 10 + U.i, '" & dtpfrom.Value & "') AS Dates 
  FROM integers H 
CROSS JOIN integers T 
CROSS JOIN integers U 
order by dates
```

The above query is displaying 999 Dates only. 999 Dates means (365 + 365 + 269) Dates Only.  Suppose I want to select more than 3 Years (01/01/2003 to 01/01/2008). The above query should not suitable.

How to modify my query? Or any other query is available for the above condition.

Please kindly provide me the Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you up to 100,000 days:

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, Y.i * 10000 + X.i * 1000 + H.i * 100 + T .i * 10 + U.i, '" & dtpfrom.Value & "') AS Dates 
FROM integers H 
CROSS JOIN integers T 
CROSS JOIN integers U 
CROSS JOIN integers X 
CROSS JOIN integers Y 
order by dates
```

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't loop to create a list of dates, use a Numbers table (not just a table of values 0 to 9), they are usefull for many things: http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html With a true Numbers table you don't have to CROSS JOIN a bunch of times and make the query overly complex.

For this method to work, you need to do this one time table setup:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.columns s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.columns s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, use this query:

```
SELECT
    @Start+Number-1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number<=DATEDIFF(day,@Start,@End)+1
```

to capture them do:

```
DECLARE  @Start datetime
         ,@End  datetime
DECLARE @AllDates table
        (Date datetime)

SELECT @Start = '06/23/2008', @End = '06/30/2008'

INSERT INTO @AllDates
        (Date)
    SELECT
        @Start+Number-1
        FROM Numbers
        WHERE Number<=DATEDIFF(day,@Start,@End)+1

SELECT * FROM @AllDates
```

output:

```
Date
-----------------------
2008-06-23 00:00:00.000
2008-06-24 00:00:00.000
2008-06-25 00:00:00.000
2008-06-26 00:00:00.000
2008-06-27 00:00:00.000
2008-06-28 00:00:00.000
2008-06-29 00:00:00.000
2008-06-30 00:00:00.000

(8 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way (not saying it's the best or most efficient) would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '06/23/2008'

DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME 
SET @EndDate = '06/30/2008'

DECLARE @TableOfDates TABLE(DateValue DATETIME)

DECLARE @CurrentDate DATETIME

SET @CurrentDate = @startDate

WHILE @CurrentDate <= @endDate
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TableOfDates(DateValue) VALUES (@CurrentDate)

    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @CurrentDate)
END

SELECT * FROM @TableOfDates
```

This will work with any number of dates, any range of dates, and doesn't need a specific "helper" table with integer values.

It stores all relevant dates into a in-memory table variable so you can then use it for e.g. another SELECT statement or whatever you need it for.

Marc

Comment: This is the ideal approach for pre-2005 because you can't use CTEs - see comments in this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/tsql-generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates/1479028#1479028

Comment: This loop will be much slower than using a traditional Numbers table, as described in my answer.  If this is a one time thing, this would be OK to use.  however, if you will generate many date ranges, use a more efficient loop free method.

Comment: Yes - but you don't have a need for an extra numbers table! And for jsut 10 or 20 rows, I don't know just how much the difference will be.

Comment: no, there wouldn't be much difference for small sets. however with the numbers table approach you can possibly integrate the query into a larger query, where with this loop method you can't.  if you have to generate date ranges for a set of start/end pairs a Numbers table is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

See:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

> A calendar table can make it much
>   easier to develop solutions around any
>   business model which involves dates.
>   Last I checked, this encompasses
>   pretty much any business model you can
>   think of, to some degree.    Constant
>   problems that end up requiring
>   verbose, complicated and inefficient
>   methods include the following
>   questions:
>
> - How many business days between x and y?
> - ...

Comment: This is a data warehousing technique, and is very powerful as you say.  It still has to be populated, though.