# Return Zero if count(*) is NULL

Tags: mysql

How can I modify my query to return 0 if count(*) is NULL?

```
select monthname(timestamp), year(timestamp), count(*) 
from largehits 
where largeID = someid 
    and (month(timestamp)<=somemonth 
    and month(timestamp)>=somemonth 
    and year(timestamp)<=someyear 
    and year(timestamp)>=someyear ) 
group by month(timestamp), year(timestamp) 
order by timestamp asc
```

Thanks!

Comment: `COUNT()` can never return NULL.

Comment: Did you mean the other way around? Returning NULL when COUNT() returns 0? A simple CASE would do that for you. I don't know what the reason would be for doing that though.

Comment: I think what you're more likely to hit is that the month/year combo doesn't exist so you get a missing row?

Comment: This query is to select hits from a range of dates . When there are no hits, it doesn't return a row for that month/year. Therefore, my resulting report doesn't have any results if there are no hits.

Comment: Basiclife, you are right I believe. Looks like I need to create a for loop in the php code to parse the date span rather than rely on the mysql result.

Comment: I think there might be some conflicting/confusing variable names in your proposed query... introduce max_month, min_month, max_year, min_year for clarification?

Answer (score 2):

BoltClock makes a good point in the comments that `COUNT` can never be `NULL`.

Generally you would just use `COALESCE(expression,0)` for this type of problem though.

**Edit:** Following clarification in the comments you would need to use an `outer join` on a numbers table to get the effect that you want.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the outer join?

Comment: Sure. It's basically the same problem as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range/3538926#3538926)