# mysql date list with count even if no data on specific date

Tags: mysql, database, gaps-and-islands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

I'm trying to make a graph from mysqldata,

```
Postid | date       | text
1      | 2012-01-01 | bla
2      | 2012-01-01 | bla
3      | 2012-01-02 | bla
4      | 2012-01-02 | bla
5      | 2012-01-04 | bla
6      | 2012-01-04 | bla
7      | 2012-01-05 | bla
```

Now, I'd like to get the number of posts on every day, INCLUDING dates with zero. For example, i'd like to be able to get the first week like this:

```
date       | count(Postid)
2012-01-01 | 2
2012-01-02 | 2
2012-01-03 | 0
2012-01-04 | 2
2012-01-05 | 1
2012-01-06 | 0
2012-01-07 | 0
```

I'm looking for a generic solution, where i don't have to specify every date. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is very difficult to do row generation in mysql, without a table of arbitrary size (so I guess you could), with rownum = rownum + 1 tricks).  I would suggest if you need to do this on the database side, that you create a table containing a suitable range of dates to do an outer join against in order to get the data that you need.  PostgreSQL has the function 'generate_series' which covers row generation, and would make this incredibly easy without another table.

Comment: [THIS ARTICLE (*click here*)](http://www.richnetapps.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/) may guide you in solving your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `postid`s are contiguous in your table, then this query:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date,
  COUNT(c.postid)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM ex) + INTERVAL 3 DAY - INTERVAL a.postid DAY AS date
  FROM
    ex a
) b
LEFT JOIN
  ex c ON c.date = b.date
GROUP BY
  b.date
ORDER BY
  b.date
```

produces:

```
date    COUNT(c.postid)
2012-01-01  2
2012-01-02  2
2012-01-03  0
2012-01-04  2
2012-01-05  1
2012-01-06  0
2012-01-07  0
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cf8d/2

If your `postid`s are not contiguous, then you can use an `ids` table of contiguous ids:

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(b.date, '%Y-%m-%d') date,
  COUNT(c.postid)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(date) FROM ex) + INTERVAL 3 DAY - INTERVAL a.id DAY AS date
  FROM
    ids a
) b
LEFT JOIN
  ex c ON c.date = b.date
GROUP BY
  b.date
ORDER BY
  b.date DESC
LIMIT 7
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13035/1

Answer (score 2):

in MySQL, I would suggest creating a Calendar table with the dates listed.  Then you will join on that table. Similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(`Postid` int, `date` datetime, `text` varchar(3));

INSERT INTO Table1(`Postid`, `date`, `text`)
VALUES
    (1, '2011-12-31 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (2, '2011-12-31 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (3, '2012-01-01 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (4, '2012-01-01 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (5, '2012-01-03 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (6, '2012-01-03 17:00:00', 'bla'),
    (7, '2012-01-04 17:00:00', 'bla');

CREATE TABLE Table2(`date` datetime);

INSERT INTO Table2(`date`)
VALUES('2011-12-31 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-01 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-02 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-03 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-04 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-05 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-06 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-07 17:00:00'),
    ('2012-01-08 17:00:00');

select t2.date, count(postid)
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1
  on t2.date = t1.date
group by t2.date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd109/3)