# SELECT appears all dates even if you do not have any content on that day

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-workbench

There is my query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS data_day
    , COUNT(*) AS count
FROM wpsa_posts
WHERE post_date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)
GROUP
    BY data_day
    ORDER BY data_day DESC
    LIMIT 7
```

THERE IS THE RESULT OF THE QUERY LIKE THAT:

[image]

IF I PUT LAST 30 DAYS THIS GONNA BE LIKE

[image]

**I want to show all the dates if i put 7(appear the last 7 days and if have nothing on this day appear 0 on count)**

Example like i want:
i want to show all dates like that example:

```
data_day     ||   count ||
2018-08-07   ||   0 if nothing on this day
2018-08-08   ||   32
2018-08-09   ||   1
2018-08-10   ||   4
2018-08-11   ||   0
2018-08-12   ||   0
2018-08-13   ||   0
```

i want to show like that

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  It would be easier to understand if you instead show sample input data, and the expected output.

Comment: i want to show all dates like that example:
data_day       ||   count ||
2018-08-07   ||       0 if nothing on this day
2018-08-08   ||      32
2018-08-09   ||     1
2018-08-10   ||      4
2018-08-11   ||       0
2018-08-12   ||     0
2018-08-13   ||     0

i want to show like that

Comment: Based on the thin information you gave us, I might suggest that what you need is a calendar table having all dates which you want to appear in your output.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: i want all dates to put on graphic and i need to have all the days because with a plugin i'm using on wordpress if no data is coming this gives error thats why i need to have 0 on count if didnt have post on this days

Comment: This issue is addressed in a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761113/mysql-date-list-with-count-even-if-no-data-on-specific-date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select All Dates In a Range Even If No Records Present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046865/mysql-select-all-dates-in-a-range-even-if-no-records-present)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have generate date values and join with your table then you can count

```
select date, count(post_date) from
(select  * from (
select 
 date_add('2018-07-17 00:00:00.000', INTERVAL n5.num*10000+n4.num*1000+n3.num*100+n2.num*10+n1.num DAY ) as date 
  from
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n1,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n2,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n3,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n4,
(select 0 as num
   union all select 1
   union all select 2
   union all select 3
   union all select 4
   union all select 5
   union all select 6
   union all select 7
   union all select 8
   union all select 9) n5
) a
where date >'2018-07-17 00:00:00.000' and date < NOW()
) as t
left join wpsa_posts w on t.date=DATE_FORMAT(w.post_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
 WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)
 group by date
```

Comment: on my case i only change the dates '2018-07-17 00:00:00.000' to '2018-07-17' and its working , thx