# MySQL showing missing dates with group by

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

I have a table where one of the columns is a timestamp.
I'd like to have a result of a per day hit count (1hit = 1row)

My actual request looks like this:

```
SELECT 
count(id) as count, 
date(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`)) as completedate 
FROM `logs` 
group by date(FROM_UNIXTIME(`time`))
order by completedate DESC 
Limit 0,20
```

This gives me this result:

```
count   completedate
1       2012-11-13
1       2012-11-12
56      2012-11-11
18      2012-11-09
```

Now I would like to have the missing:

```
count    completedate
0        2012-11-10
```

Inside of it, is this possible?