# how i can calculate last 31 days count using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

I have a table with the following columns:

- `id`,
- `submitdate`,
- `clicks`.

Now I want to retrieve the number of clicks per day from 31 days.

**If there is no records on particular date, it should be zero.**

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
SELECT 
  DATE(submitdate) 'Day',
  SUM(clicks)
FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), submitdate) <= 31
GROUP BY DATE(submitdate);
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa8ac/1)

**Update:** For this you will need to generate a list of the last n days from the current date `NOW()`. I used for this an anchor table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP 
(Digit int);
INSERT INTO Temp VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
```

Then I used it to generate a list of the last n days from now(in the demo I used 31 days but you can try it with any value less than 100, if you want to get more than 100 you will need to `CROSS JOIN temp` table one more time) I used the following query:

```
    SELECT 
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL id DAY) GDay
    FROM
    (
      SELECT t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1 AS id
      FROM         TEMP AS t1
      CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
    ) t WHERE id <= 31;
```

Then with `LEFT JOIN` you can get the last 31 days and if there are no records there will be 0 instead:

```
SELECT
  DATE(t2.GDay) 'Day', 
  SUM(IFNULL(t1.clicks, 0)) 'Count of clicks'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
      DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL id DAY) GDay
    FROM
    (
      SELECT t2.digit * 10 + t1.digit + 1 AS id
      FROM         TEMP AS t1
      CROSS JOIN TEMP AS t2
    ) t WHERE id <= 31
) t2 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1 ON DATE(t1.submitdate) = DATE(t2.GDay)
GROUP BY DATE(t2.GDay)
ORDER BY DAY DESC;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ec26/1)

Comment: this is a great demo but still doesn't answer the OP, he wants to display 0 for date that have no records. from your example, you need to show records from November 1 to November 31.

Comment: @darasaquin - Sorry, I missed this point. I updated my answer. Please review it. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for giving reply. its givig result for current date and takin too much of time

Comment: @jayamalladi - How this isn't working? What do you mean by its giving results for current date?. This should give you the list of 31 days from `now()`(current date), if you didn't need from the current date you can replace `NOW()` with any given date.

Comment: ok i got your idea. but here what i am saying is i need to take count(id). because clicks is not a int datatype.