# Show missing dates inside loop even if they don't exist inside MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I have following mysql query

`SELECT count(order_id), date FROM tbl_order WHERE campaign_status = 'In Progress' or campaign_status = 'Pending' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d %b %y')`

and then following loop

```
<?php do { ?> 
  ['<?php echo $row_chartData['date']; ?>', <?php echo $row_chartData['count(order_id)']; ?>],
<?php } while ($row_chartData = mysql_fetch_assoc($chartData)) ?>
```

this loop is used to create data for my chart. Now the problem is that there are certain days that users dont make orders in my store so those dates are not stored inside database, so when I loop trough those dates are not showed in above results and inside the chart.

The question I have, is there any way to show those missing dates in loop above even if they dont exist inside mysql database.

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Firstly make `$row_chartData` as array instead of a mysql_result.

1) find the min date in the range or whichever date you want to start with

```
function _getDate($row) {
    return $row['date'];
}
$dates = array_map('_getDate', $row_chartData);

$minDate = min($dates);
```

2) find the max date in the range or whichever date you want to end with

```
$maxDate = min($dates);

$dateRangeArray = array();

$date = $minDate;

while($date < $maxDate) {
    $dateRangeArray[] = $date;
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 day'));
}
```

3) make the key of each element in your `$row_chartdata` array be the value of the `date` index

```
foreach($row_chartData as $key => $row) {
    $row_chartData[$row['date']] = $row;
    unset($row_chartData[$key]);
}
```

4) iterate over each of the days in the range and match that date to the index in your `$row_chartdata` array

foreach($dateRangeArray as $date) {
    if(isset($row_chartData[$date])) {
        //do whatever
    }
}

Comment: thanks, gone try this out and see if it works, will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, create a temporary array based on the date range, e.g. if you want to show the graph from May 1, to May 31.
Loop from 1 to 30,

```
set $data[i] = 0;
```

Now loop through the db records and set

```
$data['date'] = $row['count']
```