# Mysql query to produce 'bin'ed sums along with other aggregates in a group by query

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to product a result set like

```
 select 
  customer
  bin_sum(sales,margin_pct,0.5), 
  count(1) txns, 
  sum(sales) total_sales, 
  sum(margin) total margin
 from sales_txns
 group by customer
```

Such that "bin_sum" will produce either an array or csv_list containing the customers aggregate according to 'bins' of 5 pct increments. The output of this column will contain the aggregate of sales havent 0-5% margin, 5-10% margin, 10-15% margin, etc, such that the output of this field is

```
customer1|"0,0,234.24,2632.45,4567.50,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"|37|783736.429|22443.23
customer2|"0,54.50,284.24,5632.45,2567.50,460,0,0,0,0,0,0"|37|783736.429|22443.23
```

The goal here to to be able to produce a graph of profit distribution by profit percentage from the second field. We've been iterating the sales records, and keeping a running tally of the fields in application logic, but I am wondering if a sql guru knows how to do this entirely in SQL.

Comment: How second column is calculated ? can you provide the example of your bin_sum scenario

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming data that looks something like this:

```
| CUSTOMER |  SALE | MARGIN_PCT |
|----------|-------|------------|
|        1 | 10.12 |          2 |
|        1 | 12.99 |         39 |
|        1 | 20.95 |         16 |
|        1 | 80.00 |         18 |
|        2 | 94.99 |         17 |
|        2 | 92.98 |         70 |
```

First, we find which "bin" each transaction falls into:

```
select customer, sale, floor(margin_pct/5) as bin from sales
```

Then take those results and roll them up into bins per customer:

```
select customer, sum(sale) total_sales, bin
from
 (select customer, sale, floor(margin_pct/5) as bin from sales) customer_bins
group by customer, bin
```

Finally, take *those* results and roll them up per customer:

```
select customer, group_concat(total_sales separator ', ')
from
  (
   select customer, sum(sale) total_sales, pct_group
   from
    (select customer, sale, floor(margin_pct/5) as bin from sales) customer_bins
   group by customer, pct_group
   ) binned
group by customer
```

This gives

```
| CUSTOMER |       BINNED_MARGINS |
|----------|----------------------|
|        1 | 100.95, 12.99, 10.12 |
|        2 |         94.99, 92.98 |
```

We are almost there, but clearly we have a big problem.  Unless you can **guarantee** that you will always have records that fall into **every bin**, your results won't make much sense.

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't offer an elegant solution to this.  Your best option is to [make a range table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538926/701303) to join against.  Simply:

```
| BIN |
|-----|
|   0 |
|   1 |
|   2 |
|   3 |
|   4 |
|   5 |
|   6 |
|   7 |
|   8 |
|   9 |
```

Finally, by joining against the `bin` and `customer` tables we can force values for all bins:

```
select customer, group_concat(total_sales separator ', ') as binned_margins
from
  (
   select customer, sum(sale) total_sales, bin
   from
    (
      select customer, ifnull(sale, 0) sale, bin
      from bin
      inner join customer
      left join (select customer, sale, floor(margin_pct/5) as bin from sales) customer_sale_bins
      using(customer, bin)
      order by customer, bin 
    ) customer_bins
   group by customer, bin
   ) binned
group by customer
```

Produces:

```
| CUSTOMER |                                                 BINNED_MARGINS |
|----------|----------------------------------------------------------------|
|        1 | 10.12, 0.00, 0.00, 100.95, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 12.99, 0.00, 0.00 |
|        2 |    0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 94.99, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7c5b/7)