# Show empty date from interval data

Tags: mysql

How to Show empty date from interval data, MySQl Query:

```
select data, dt from dt_tb where dt >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

will show:

```
  data 1 : 2013-05-01
  data 2 : 2013-05-02
  data 3 : 2013-05-03
  data 6 : 2013-05-06
```

I would like to get:

```
data 1 : 2013-05-01
data 2 : 2013-05-02
data 3 : 2013-05-03
null   : 2013-05-04
null   : 2013-05-05
data 6 : 2013-05-06
null   : 2013-05-07
```

Comment: You should look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

Comment: Also, you need to generate `date` range like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range) and join that query result with your current `dt_tb` table.