# MySQL LEFT JOIN with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that must returns the values from table `Share_users_types` that do not exists in table `Shares` according to some conditions.

```
Share_types table
----------------
ID | Description
1    'Anual'
2    'Monthly'

Share_users_types table
-----------------------------
ID | user_id  | share_type_id
1    1          1
2    1          2
3    2          1

Shares table
--------------------------------------------
ID | user_id  | share_type_id | Year | Month 
1    1          1               2015   null
2    1          2               2015   05
3    1          1               2016   null
4    2          1               2015   null
```

If I set the following conditions in my query, it should return from the table `Share_users_type`:

1. Year `2016`, Share type `Anual` -> 1 results -> `User_id`: 2
2. Year `2015`, Share type `Anual` -> 0 results
3. Year `2017`, Share type `Anual` -> 2 results -> `User_id`: 1 and 2
4. Year `2017`, Month 06, Share type `Monthly` ->  1 result -> `User_id`: 1

With this said I have tried without any success the following queries:

```
SELECT sharetype.user_id 
FROM share_users_types AS sharetype
LEFT JOIN shares AS share ON share.user_id = sharetype.user_id
WHERE share.user_id IS NULL AND
share.year != '2016' AND share_type_id = 1

SELECT sharetype.user_id 
FROM share_users_types AS sharetype
LEFT JOIN shares AS share ON share.user_id = sharetype.user_id
WHERE share.year = '2016' AND share_type_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use not in

```
    SELECT sharetype.user_id 
    FROM share_users_types AS sharetype
    where sharetype.user_id not in  (select  user_id from share where share.year != '2016' AND share_type_id = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting results for 2015 - 1016 are relatively easy. First you need to create a carthesian join of user_id - share_type_id and year values and left join shares table on this resultset:

```
select distinct sut.user_id, sut.share_type_id, s.year
from (Share_users_types sut
join shares s)
left join shares s2
    on sut.user_id=s2.user_id and sut.share_type_id=s2.share_type and s.year=s2.year and s2.year is null
```

The problem is if you add 2017 or any other year to the mix, that do not exist in the shares table. Mysql in itself cannot select a value that is not there.

Either you need to create a calendar table, or use a series of unions to list all years and combine this with the Share_users_types table.

See [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range) for guidance on this.