# one mysql query for all count of orders on each day

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create generic query for generating various reports on day selection.

For example,

for last 7 days order value, I need following output.

Order Date  Order Value

```
2014-05-15 - 700
2014-05-16 - 0
2014-05-17 - 100
2014-05-18 - 0
2014-05-19 - 0
2014-05-20 - 0
2014-05-21 - 200
```

if order data is not presented for the date then 0 should be displayed on that date.

Comment: You can use "SELECT order_date, COALESCE(NULLIF(order_value, ""), "0") as order_value'

Comment: it is a problem to show absent dates in sql query. You need or write a procedure or add them in php

Comment: the order value will be count of all orders on that day

Comment: do you want only sql solution or php-code too?

Comment: @splash58 I only want mysql solution

Answer (score 0):

If order value is a number of orders that day it should have been defaulted to 0 in MySQL table. If it's not it's an error and should be fixed but let's assume you can't change it, in that case you can do it at MySQL query level using `COALESCE` function.

Let's say your table is `orders_stats` and `order_value` is integer.

```
SELECT `order_date`, COALESCE(`order_value`, 0) as `order_value` FROM `orders_stats`;
```

This query works the same way as:

```
SELECT `order_date`, `order_value` FROM `orders_stats`;
```

the difference is `order_value` will be set to `0` if it's `null`.

More on COALESCE can be found on [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) and [w3resource.com](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php).

Comment: what if the record for any date is not available in table ? I want such date in output with date and 0 value

Comment: @BhaveshPatel Here is an answer to your question [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3538858/2008285)

Comment: thanks for quick answer @Linek. I will check this solution tonight