# Get data by week with sql and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.3, php-5.6

I have a problem and I have no idea how to do that. Please help me with an idea. So I have a table : `test`, with columns :

```
id        begin                    end     
1       2016-06-06 15:30:30     2016-06-08 16:40:40
```

Now I need to get the count of id by week
The result need to be :
For example if this week is the week number 6 I need to get :

```
Week           count
 4               10
 5               10
 6               12
 7               19
 8               27
```

Thx four you help

Comment: you should better explain the expected result.

Comment: If the current week is 6 I need to get the count from table `test` for the weeks `4,5,6,7,8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what happens if the `begin` is week 4, and `end` is week 5? which week is calculated?

Anyway, if I understood you, you want two previous weeks and 2 future weeks :

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(`start`) as year_col,WEEK(`start`) as week_col,count(*)
    FROM YourTable t
    GROUP BY year_col,week_col) s
WHERE s.week_col between WEEK(now())-2 and WEEK(now())+2
```

I've also added year into the consideration, since week 4 from 2015 will be group together with week 4 from 2016. If its not possible, exclude it from the query.

Comment: how to show `week 7 count 0` if for this week no data ?

Comment: That's a whole different question mate.. @hareacosticla

Comment: can you help me please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range . This is the same as your problem, follow the steps. @hareacpsticla

Comment: I have a problem with this sql..because if are data in multiple years...for example for week = 23 are data in database, then it's get data for week=23 for year 2015,2014,...

Comment: @HareaCosticla Then just filter those years, everything explained in the post, you can choose the dates you'd like