# Return values even if null, 0 or not present

Tags: mysql, null, zero, mysql-5.5

I want to create some reports so I can grab data quickly regarding our helpdesk, I am using GLPI which is running on MySQL 5.5

I have the below code and it returns some useful information but not enough so it can be put into a pretty stacked graph which is what he has requested. To get enough data to achieve this I need the urgency's that are zero and the days that are also zero, then I can convert the data into a table in Excel and build the graph.

Current Query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Date,Urgency,COUNT(*) as Tickets 
FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
WHERE month(date)=month(NOW())
GROUP BY urgency ORDER BY date,urgency ASC;
```

This returns:

```
# Date, Urgency, Tickets
'07/06/2016', '3', '10'
'10/06/2016', '2', '1'
'14/06/2016', '1', '1'
'14/06/2016', '5', '1'
```

I would ideally like it to display as below:

```
# Date, Urgency, Tickets
'07/06/2016', '1', '0'
'07/06/2016', '2', '0'
'07/06/2016', '3', '10'
'07/06/2016', '4', '0'
'07/06/2016', '5', '0'
'08/06/2016', '1', '0'
'08/06/2016', '2', '0'
'08/06/2016', '3', '0'
'08/06/2016', '4', '0'
'08/06/2016', '5', '0'
...
'14/06/2016', '1', '1'
'14/06/2016', '2', '0'
'14/06/2016', '3', '0'
'14/06/2016', '4', '0'
'14/06/2016', '5', '1'
```

And so on.

I am kind of getting the hang of SQL (self teaching) so all and any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Schema added, I think this is what you was asking for (hope it works) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/715c7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

Comment: I just add that you need to produce a Cartesian join on your urgency list and your dates to get the full list.

Comment: post your schema or create one on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Schema added http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/715c7

Comment: Just having a thought, would I be better off creating a stored procedure to query the `glpi_tickets` table each night, take a count of total tickets logged that day and their urgencies and then store them in a table called `COMPANYNAME_TICKETSTATS`. Column names would be `DATE`,`TOTAL_TICKETS`,`VERY_LOW`,`LOW`,`MEDIUM`,`HIGH`,`VERY_HIGH` and they would have the total number of tickets with a 1,2,3,4,5 urgency underneath for that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I ended up doing and it appears to be supplying the data just how I want it.

First of all I created a new table to store the data in:

```
    CREATE TABLE glpi_plugin_ns_ticketstats
    (
    id INT(11),
    daterun date,
    timerun time,
    totaltickets INT(11),
    verylow INT(11),
    low INT(11),
    med INT(11),
    high INT(11),
    veryhigh INT(11));
```

Then I built a stored procedure to collect and populate the data:

```
USE `glpi`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Daily_Ticket_Stats`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `glpi`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Daily_Ticket_Stats`()
BEGIN
declare todayd date;
## Declaring the variable for the daterun column ##
declare todayt time;
## Declaring the variable for the timerun column ##
declare totalt int(11);
## Declaring the variable for totaltickets column ##
declare vlow int (11);
## Declaring the variable for verylow column ##
declare low int(11);
## Declaring the variable for low column ##
declare med int(11);
## Declaring the variable for med column ##
declare high int (11);
## Declaring the variable for high column ##
declare vhigh int(11);
## Declaring the variable for veryhigh column ##
    set todayd = CURDATE();
    ## Set date to today ##
    set todayt = CURTIME();
    ## Set time to now ##
    set totalt = (SELECT COUNT(*) as ttickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW()));
    ## This has set the total for the total tickets variable ##
    set vlow = (SELECT COUNT(*) as vltickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW())
        AND urgency = '1');
    ## This has set the total for the very low urgency tickets variable ##
    set low = (SELECT COUNT(*) as ltickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW())
        AND urgency = '2');
    ## This has set the total for the low urgency tickets variable ##
    set med = (SELECT COUNT(*) as mtickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW())
        AND urgency = '3');
    ## This has set the total for the medium urgency tickets variable ##
    set high = (SELECT COUNT(*) as htickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW())
        AND urgency = '4');
    ## This has set the total for the high urgency tickets variable ##
    set vhigh = (SELECT COUNT(*) as vhtickets 
        FROM glpi.glpi_tickets
    WHERE day(date)=day(NOW())
        AND urgency = '5');

IF EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM glpi.glpi_plugin_ns_ticketstats 
    WHERE daterun = CURDATE())
    THEN
BEGIN
    UPDATE glpi.glpi_plugin_ns_ticketstats 
SET 
    timerun = CURTIME(),
    totaltickets = totalt,
    verylow = vlow,
    low = low,
    med = med,
    high = high,
    veryhigh = vhigh
WHERE
    daterun = CURDATE();
END;
ELSE
INSERT INTO glpi.glpi_plugin_ns_ticketstats VALUES (NULL,todayd,todayt,totalt,vlow,low,med,high,vhigh);
END IF;
END
#$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I then set this procedure to run every hour so the stats are recent if my manager wishes to refer to them during the day (I entered this directly onto the mysql server terminal):

```
CREATE EVENT TicketStatusUpdate
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 29 MINUTE
DO
CALL Daily_Ticket_Stats();
```

The 29 minute is because I wanted it to run as close to the hour as I could get it.

This now outputs lovely data in a format that allows me to create a stacked graph in Excel (Spoofed entries from 1st-16th June so I had entries from start of month):

```
# id, daterun, timerun, totaltickets, verylow, low, med, high, veryhigh
'1', '2016-06-01', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'2', '2016-06-02', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'3', '2016-06-03', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'4', '2016-06-04', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'5', '2016-06-05', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'6', '2016-06-06', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'7', '2016-06-07', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'8', '2016-06-08', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'9', '2016-06-09', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'10', '2016-06-10', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'11', '2016-06-11', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'12', '2016-06-12', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'13', '2016-06-13', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'14', '2016-06-14', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'15', '2016-06-15', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'16', '2016-06-16', '23:00:00', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'
'17', '2016-06-17', '12:31:22', '4', '1', '0', '0', '0', '3'
```

This then lets me do a `select` so I only get the current month imported into Excel:

```
select * from glpi.glpi_plugin_ns_ticketstats
where month(daterun)=month(NOW())
```

I'll leave this here so if anyone wants to use it they can, thanks everyone for your time and help :)

iFr4g

Answer (score 1):

Your query produces one row per `urgency` because you only group by that column.  In order to see distinct results for each date and urgency you must modify your GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') AS Date,
    Urgency,
    COUNT(*) as Tickets 
FROM 
    glpi.glpi_tickets
WHERE 
    month(date)=month(NOW())
GROUP BY 
    DATE(date),
    urgency 
ORDER BY 
    date, urgency ASC;
```

Comment: Close, but I need to have the urgency stats for dates where there is no reference of the date or urgency. See my schema here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/715c7

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Though I did not have the schema, I tried to write the query. I think this is what you are looking for. (Please check the SQL, I have edited. It should generate a report like how you want, only missing records are, if there is no data for a date.)

```
    select DATE_FORMAT(dummy.date,'%d/%m/%Y') Date, dummy.Urgency, ifnull(main.Tickets, 0) Tickets  from 
(select * from 
(select distinct date(date) date from glpi_tickets
    WHERE month(date)=month(NOW()) ) dates
cross join 
(select distinct Urgency from glpi_tickets) urgency
order by Date, Urgency) dummy
left join 
(SELECT date(date) date, Urgency, COUNT(*) as Tickets 
FROM glpi_tickets
WHERE month(date)=month(NOW())
GROUP BY date(date), Urgency  
ORDER BY date(date), Urgency) main
on dummy.date = main.date
and dummy.Urgency = main.Urgency
order by dummy.date asc, Urgency asc
```

I guess the below SQL will serve your purpose, I took a little help from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97773/get-all-dates-in-the-current-month). You need to optimize the query for big data.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(dummy.date,'%d/%m/%Y') Date, dummy.Urgency, ifnull(main.Tickets, 0) Tickets  from 
(select * from 
(SELECT date_field date
FROM
(SELECT
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) +
        INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-1) MONTH +
        INTERVAL daynum DAY date_field
    FROM
    (SELECT t*10+u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
    ) AA
) AAA
WHERE MONTH(date_field) = MONTH(NOW())
and date_field >= (select min(date(date)) from glpi_tickets WHERE month(date)=month(NOW())) 
and date_field <= (select max(date(date)) from glpi_tickets WHERE month(date)=month(NOW())) ) dates
cross join 
(select distinct Urgency from glpi_tickets) urgency
order by date, Urgency) dummy
left join 
(SELECT date(date) date, Urgency, COUNT(*) as Tickets 
FROM glpi_tickets
WHERE month(date)=month(NOW())
GROUP BY date(date), Urgency  
ORDER BY date(date), Urgency) main
on dummy.date = main.date
and dummy.Urgency = main.Urgency
order by dummy.date asc, Urgency asc
```

Comment: Close to what I want however it doesn't show every date in what's returned, it's also displaying stats from last month. See http://pastebin.com/HCUgwG36 for what came from my database.

Comment: Modified the urgency on my data to give a better example http://pastebin.com/hfj8Npwa . Schema can be found here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/715c7

Comment: I have no idea if you get an alert when I comment on the main post but do you think this would work @ghkhan ? If I create a stored procedure to query the `glpi_tickets` table each night, take a count of total tickets logged that day and their urgencies and then store them in a table called `COMPANYNAME_TICKETSTATS`. Column names would be `DATE`,`TOTAL_TICKETS`,`VERY_LOW`,`LOW`,`MEDIUM`,`HIGH`,`VERY_HIGH` and they would have the total number of tickets with a 1,2,3,4,5 urgency underneath for that day. Then I would have the data I want in the format I need to create a stacked graph I think.

Comment: yes, possible. you can do that. I believe which will be more simple.