# Convert select statement using trunc() and sysdate from Oracle SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

This below Oracle query returns dates between last day of previous month till today. I need same results in  MySQL. Can anybody help me to write the query in MySQL?

Please note that I have drive this query on 'DUAL'. There is no physical/actual table.

```
SELECT TRUNC(TRUNC(TRUNC(sysdate,'MM')-1)+level)-1 attendance_date
FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level<= (TRUNC(sysdate)-TRUNC(sysdate,'mm'))+2;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL simply doesn't have the nonstandard Oracle `CONNECT BY` feature. It doesn't yet have the standard recursive common table expression feature. Your present approach to your problem isn't the right one to get a sequence of dates.

There are other ways to to get a sequence of dates.

[MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/filling-missing-data-sequences-cardinal-integers/