# Add a 0 if there is no SUM for a given date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, select, ifnull

I been trying to make this one work, but can't find a solution.

I want to grab the `SUM` of a row for a given date, and if there is no entry for that date, return a `0`. I tried using `IFNULL()` but can't make it work.

My query grabs the data for the last 15 dates and `SUMS` the content for each date. Here is the query

```
SELECT date(left(date_column, 10)) as dd, ROUND(SUM(sum_total)/1000)
as cnt FROM order_table WHERE date(left(date_column, 10)) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) 
GROUP BY date(left(date_column, 10)) ORDER BY dd ASC
```

I tried

```
SELECT date(left(date_column, 10)) as dd, IFNULL ( ROUND(SUM(sum_total)/1000) ,'0') 
FROM order_table WHERE date(left(date_column, 10)) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) 
GROUP BY date(left(date_column, 10)) ORDER BY dd ASC
```

My problem occurs when there is no data for a given date and therefore the date is skipped.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated

Comment: I would do this in code instead of SQL. Really not even sure how you would do it in SQL.

Comment: Your `group by` resultset does not contain dates the original data doesn't have, so there is nothing `ifnull` would work on. You have to add rows with the missing dates. Try e.g. [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range) (or any similar solution) with your resultset.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a regular IF function and test for null that way.

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that date or count won't be never null, just not consecutive. I think that is why IFNULL is also not working, because there is a date value, just not consecutive.