# Loop into a query and an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table containing some date for dates:

#### ___BillableDatas:

```
|----------|------------|---------------|
|BIL_Id    | BIL_Date   | BIL_BookingID |
|----------|------------|---------------|
| 1        | 2017-01-01 | 10            |
| 2        | 2017-01-02 | 10            |
| 3        | 2017-01-06 | 11            |
| 4        | 2017-01-07 | 11            |
| 5        | 2017-01-08 | 11            |
| 6        | 2017-01-12 | 14            |
|----------|------------|---------------|
```

And I have this array giving me all the dates between two dates:

```
$dates = getDatesFromRange('2017-01-01', '2017-01-15');

Array ( [0] => 2017-01-01 [1] => 2017-01-02 [2] => 2017-01-03 [3] => 2017-01-04 [4] => 2017-01-05 [5] => 2017-01-06 [6] => 2017-01-07 [7] => 2017-01-08 [8] => 2017-01-09 [9] => 2017-01-10 [10] => 2017-01-11 [11] => 2017-01-12 [12] => 2017-01-13 [13] => 2017-01-14 )
```

---

I want to be able to loop into this table to get all the days between a period (from `2017-01-01` to `2017-01-15` for example).

For example, the desired output should be the following Json or array:

```
"datas": {
    "2017-01-01": {
        "bookingId": "10"
    },
    "2017-01-02": {
        "bookingId": "10"
    },
    "2017-01-03": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-04": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-05": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-06": {
        "bookingId": "11"
    },
    "2017-01-07": {
        "bookingId": "11"
    },
    "2017-01-08": {
        "bookingId": "11"
    },
    "2017-01-09": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-10": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-11": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-12": {
        "bookingId": "14"
    },
    "2017-01-13": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-14": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    },
    "2017-01-15": {
        "bookingId": "0"
    }
}
```

Comment: whats `getDatesFromRange()` function? you made this one? just modify it, looks like you could just change the array on how you want it constructed in the structure above, one way would be to just loop the days over from start to end and create the array

Comment: if you want to do it in the db layer, you could pad the empty dates, here's the idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range there are other topics also just search for it, i'd do it in the application layer though

Comment: where is this **___BillableDatas** table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am not wrong you wants result including all the date range between two dates regardless it's present in DB table or not

you can loop and compare available date and create your desire array or json.

```
$new_array = array();
 foreach ($dates as $date){  // date range from "2017-01-01" to "2017-01-15"  
     $avalilable = 0;
        foreach ($bills as $bill){ // records From __BillableDatas table 
            if($bill->BIL_Date == $date)
            {
                $avalilable = 1;
                $new_array[$date] = array("bookingId" =>  $bill->BIL_BookingID);
                break;  
            }   
    } 
    if(!$avalilable)
        $new_array[$date] = array("bookingId" =>  0);
 }
   echo  json_encode($new_array);
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Excellent. Really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then below is the way to calculate number of days between 2 dates. No need for loop.Comment on this if you think otherwise

```
<?php
$from = strtotime('2017-01-01'); 
$to = strtotime("2017-01-15");
$datediff = $to - $from;

echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

?>
```

Comment: Ho I can get the same with me function. The problem is the bulid the output by combining the datas info my table. If the date exists into the db take it.