# How can I SELECT rows with multiple columns where a column includes different values and GROUP BY date?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL db `company` with table `department` (the departments in the table are sales and marketing), table `campaign`, table `product`. And two join tables `department_campaign` and `department_product`.

Each campaign has 3 promotions every day. The results of the daily promotions are stored in the table `promotion_result`. For instance see the rows if the campaign_id = 1:

```
    "created"          "campaign_id"    "promotion"   "product_id"
2020-02-06 09:42:59          1               a             281
2020-02-06 13:35:22          1               b            (null)
2020-02-06 17:55:43          1               c            (null)
2020-02-07 14:42:59          1               a             350
2020-02-07 14:42:59          1               b             350
2020-02-07 14:42:59          1               c            (null)
2020-02-08 14:42:59          1               a            (null)
2020-02-08 14:42:59          1               b            (null)
2020-02-08 14:42:59          1               c            (null)
```

In the `column` "product_id" is the product, which was sold with the promotion at the "created" time.

I would like to have one query to get a list where I can see for each day, which product with which promotion was sold by a department. If there was no product sold on a day then I would like to see to that day only one row with (null).
I tried with this query in mysql:

```
SELECT DATE(pr.created) AS created, pr.campaign_id AS campaign, pr.promotion AS promotion, pr.product_id AS product
FROM department AS dept
          LEFT JOIN department_campaign AS dc ON dc.department_id = dept.id
          LEFT JOIN department_products AS dp ON dp.department_id = dept.id
          LEFT JOIN promotion_result AS pr ON dc.campaign_id = pr.campaign_id
          WHERE dept.id = 2 AND pr.campaign_id = 1
          GROUP BY DATE(pr.created), product_id, promotion
          ORDER BY DATE(pr.created) ASC, promotion ASC
```

The result:

```
   "created"    "campaign"   "promotion"    "product"
  2020-02-06         1            a            281
  2020-02-06         1            b           (null)
  2020-02-06         1            c           (null)
  2020-02-07         1            a            350
  2020-02-07         1            b            350
  2020-02-07         1            c           (null)
  2020-02-08         1            a           (null)
  2020-02-08         1            b           (null)
  2020-02-08         1            c           (null)
```

If I add `AND dp.product_id = pr.product_id` to the `where` then I get only the days where products were sold but not the day(s) whitout sales:

```
"created"    "campaign"  "promotion"    "product"
2020-02-06       1            a            281
2020-02-07       1            a            350
2020-02-07       1            b            350
```

What expected:

```
   "created"    "campaign"   "promotion"    "product"
  2020-02-06         1            a            281
  2020-02-07         1            a            350
  2020-02-07         1            b            350
  2020-02-08         1          (null)        (null)
```

In this case I could see each day with sold products per promotion and also the days without sales ("product" = (null) and "promotion" = (null))

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found a solution using `SELECT DISTINCT` and `UNION` to get the expected result. I share it so that it can may help others, too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(pr.created) AS created, pr.campaign_id AS campaign, pr.promotion AS promotion, pr.product_id AS product
FROM department AS dept
LEFT JOIN department_campaign AS dc ON dc.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN department_products AS dp ON dp.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_result AS pr ON pr.product_id = dp.product_id
WHERE dept.id = 2 AND pr.campaign_id = 1
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(pr.created) AS created, pr.campaign_id AS campaign, NULL, pr.product_id AS product
FROM department AS dept
LEFT JOIN department_campaign AS dc ON dc.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN department_products AS dp ON dp.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_result AS pr ON dc.campaign_id = pr.campaign_id
WHERE dept.id = 2 AND pr.campaign_id = 1 AND pr.product_id is NULL AND DATE(pr.created) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE(pr1.created)
FROM department AS dept1
LEFT JOIN department_campaign AS dc1 ON dc1.department_id = dept1.id
LEFT JOIN department_products AS dp1 ON dp1.department_id = dept1.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_result AS pr1 ON pr1.product_id = dp1.product_id
WHERE dept1.id = 2 AND pr1.campaign_id = 1)
ORDER BY created ASC, promotion ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(pr.created) created
              , pr.campaign_id campaign
              , pr.promotion 
              , pr.product_id product
           FROM department d
           LEFT 
           JOIN department_campaign dc 
             ON dc.department_id = d.id
           LEFT 
           JOIN department_products dp 
             ON dp.department_id = dept.id
           LEFT 
           JOIN promotion_result pr 
             ON pr.campaign_id = dc.campaign_id 
            AND pr.product_id = dp.product_id  
            AND pr.campaign_id = 1
          WHERE d.id = 2 
          ORDER 
             BY DATE(pr.created) ASC, promotion ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get with your query the same results listed as I already had with my query using group by.

Comment: Oops - missed that

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality.
The given answer will work for PostgreSQL database.

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538926/10086603 answer for generating dates in a table and right join it similiarly.

> Add condition while left joining promotion_result instead in "where".
>
> Generate series helps to fill the missing dates. (PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT DATE(pr.created) AS created,
       pr.campaign_id AS campaign,
       pr.promotion AS promotion,
       pr.product_id AS product
FROM department AS dept
LEFT JOIN department_campaign AS dc ON dc.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN department_products AS dp ON dp.department_id = dept.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_result AS pr ON dc.campaign_id = pr.campaign_id
AND dp.product_id = pr.product_id
AND pr.campaign_id = 1
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT generate_series(TIMESTAMP '2020-02-01' , TIMESTAMP '2020-02-01' + interval '1 month - 1 day' , interval '1 day')::date as day) d ON pr.created = d.day
WHERE dept.id = 2
GROUP BY DATE(pr.created),
         product_id,
         promotion
ORDER BY DATE(pr.created) ASC, promotion ASC
```

Comment: It doesn´t work. I get only the rows where product was sold and plus a row only with (null) in all columns including created. So I can´t see on which day was no sale.

Comment: @bm82 I have made some changes to above answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: I get SQL error (1064): ... near 'interval '1 day'):: date as day) d ON sr.created = d.day WHERE'

Comment: MySQL doesn't have recursive functionality.
The given answer will work only on PostgreSQL database. 

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3538926/10086603 answer for generating dates in a table and right join it similiarly. @bm82

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn´t work if you have more than one result per day. I´ve found a solution and posted it here.