# Mysql dates of the last 30 days

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I need help with some dates in mysql

I have this query that brings me the count of the messages of the corresponding dates of every message from the last 30 days.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, count(*) as count 
FROM ma_messages 
WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
AND usersid_send = 110 
Group by Dates 
ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvzkx.png)

But I need that also bring me the other dates of the last 30 days with a value in the count of 0, for example that in the query also bring me 05/26/2021 date and the dates before 05/25/2021 and after 05/28/2021.

I don't know if this is possible, but I will apreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Generate dates list (calendar) and leftjoin your data to it.

Comment: Hello, I have a table with dates but  I'm new in this and I don't know how to do that leftjoin but thank you anyways

Comment: *I have a table with dates* It includes all dates? including the dates which are absent in data table?

Comment: Yes, is a table with all the dates of the year

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL how to fill missing dates in range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range)

Comment: not quite, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(time, '%m/%d/%Y') AS Dates, 
count(if(usersid_send='110',true,null)) as count 
FROM ma_messages 
WHERE time BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
Group by Dates 
ORDER BY Dates ASC
```

Comment: Ok, it bring me like I said the 05/26/2021 date and also the 06/07/2021 date but the rest of the days of the last 30 days is not bring it, thank you anyways, maybe I can do something with this

Answer (score 0):

> I have a table with dates .. with all the dates of the year – Alexis Murillo

```sql
SELECT d.`date`, COUNT(m.`time`) AS `count`
FROM dates_table d
LEFT JOIN ma_messages m ON d.`date` = DATE(m.`time`)
WHERE d.`date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW() 
  AND m.usersid_send = 110 
GROUP BY d.`date`
ORDER BY d.`date` ASC
```

Comment: It doesn't bring me the other dates of the last 30 days with count 0, but at least it has the left join with the dates table, I appreciate anyways

Answer (score 0):

Using your table *"with all the dates of the year"*:

```
WITH
message_counts AS (  SELECT DATE_FORMAT("time", '%m/%d/%Y') AS "day", 
                            COUNT(*) AS "count" 
                       FROM ma_messages 
                      WHERE "time" BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
                            AND
                            usersid_send = 110 
                   GROUP BY Dates)                         
   SELECT all_dates."day", COALESCE(message_counts."count", 0)
     FROM all_dates
LEFT JOIN message_counts
          ON all_dates."day" = message_counts."day"
    WHERE all_dates."day" BETWEEN BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
 ORDER BY all_dates."day" ASC
```