# Generate Daily Balance From Transaction Table

Tags: mysql

List item

I have this type of records:

| ... | user_id | ... | ondate | ... | current_balance | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-06-30 05:21:03 | ... | 20.95629595 | ... |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-07-02 10:17:25 | ... | 21.95629595 | ... |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-07-02 11:07:23 | ... | 20.95629595 | ... |
| ... | 14 | ... | 2021-07-02 11:40:34 | ... | 1.42046290 | ... |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-07-02 11:59:15 | ... | 21.87674098 | ... |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-07-02 12:06:12 | ... | 22.79712675 | ... |
| ... | 1 | ... | 2021-07-02 12:24:11 | ... | 21.79712675 | ... |
| ... | 14 | ... | 2021-07-02 12:37:11 | ... | 11.42046290 | ... |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And I'm aiming to this result in MySQL:

| user_id | date | average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-30 | 20.956295950000 |
| 1 | 2021-07-01 | 20.956295950000 |
| 1 | 2021-07-02 | 17.460644597143 |
| 1 | 2021-07-03 | 17.460644597143 |
| 1 | 2021-07-04 | 17.460644597143 |
| 1 | 2021-07-05 | 17.460644597143 |
| ... until the next date it has a different average value |  |  |

If the next date after the average being calculated doesn't have any value, it will populate with previous average value.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT c.date,AVG(IFNULL(a.current_balance,0)) AS balance FROM users_balancemaster a 
RIGHT JOIN calendar c ON c.date= DATE(a.ondate) GROUP BY c.date
```

but it return zeros on dates where there's no average.

```
+---------+------------+-----------------+
| user_id | date       |     average     |
+---------+------------+-----------------+
|    1    | 2021-06-30 | 20.956295950000 |
|    1    | 2021-07-01 | 0.000000000000  | <<--
|    1    | 2021-07-02 | 17.460644597143 | 
|    1    | 2021-07-03 | 0.000000000000  | <<--
|    1    | 2021-07-04 | 0.000000000000  | <<--
|    1    | 2021-07-05 | 0.000000000000  | <<--
....
```

Comment: try a solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range

Comment: i want to above row current_balance in missing date row

Comment: i understand that, but if you read the provided link there is exactly that described and solutions presented, in Mysql is no othger solution make a time table and left join it

Comment: but link solution provide only '0' in missing date i want is above row current_balance

Comment: which version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the version you are using is not known to me, so i choose MysQL 5.7.

```
SELECT
`date`,
IF(balance IS NULL, @balance, @balance := balance) balance
FROM (select c.`date`
,AVG( a.current_balance)  as balance from users_balancemaster a 
RIGHT join calendar c on c.date= date(a.ondate) 
GROUP BY c.date
ORDER BY c.date) t1,(SELECT @balance := 0) t2
```

see [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f3b0b0e792b6045f61a6d4fd3214a9d6)