# Writing a SQL query to produce graph over a date range when zero results on certain days

Tags: mysql

I.e. imagine a date range of the current month. How to get the 0 sum data in that query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), created_date FROM my_table GROUP BY created_date;
```

Only produces results for the days that have any records. How do I produce a query that shows the 0 count for days where the records don't exist in the DB?

The problem I'm trying to solve is essentially to produce a graph of the total of X per day in the month, when on some days of the month the total = 0, hence no records in the DB. Since the existing query produces missing days which users find annoying.

### Response to suggested duplicate

The proposed duplicate question/answer is a very old thread, [MySQL doesn't support recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538858/mysql-how-to-fill-missing-dates-in-range), which may not be ideal for me. Recursion has existed in MySQL since v. 8.0 which launched April 2018.

### Update

I've had a deeper dive into the more recent answers on that 13 year old thread and someone has kindly provided a MySQL 8 version of this solution using recursion.

Comment: I am not one of the voter who closed your question, but your question is closed because the answer to your question is still the same as in the link attached, whether recursion had existed or not at that time.

Comment: Thanks @Eric that's useful to know. I've had a deeper dive into the more recent answers on that 13 year old thread and someone has kindly provided a MySQL 8 version of this solution using recursion. I'll have a play.

Comment: I've edited out the snark from the question. The takeaway here is that people aren't closing questions for fun, they are doing it to be helpful and they are signposting you to the answer.