# How do I fetch data grouped by month and year including the period with no data?

Tags: sql, select, null, count

Relatively new to SQL and I am stumped on this little issue. This doesn't seem to be very difficult to do, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to get a count of transactions from a table, but I can't seem to get sql to get me to show all of the months instead of only the months and the year that the transactions occured in.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT      YEAR(dbo.countproject.trans_date)   AS [TransYear]
        ,   MONTH (dbo.countproject.trans_date) AS [TransMonth]
        ,   COUNT(Id)                           AS TransNum 
FROM        dbo.countproject
WHERE       dbo.countproject.make_name  = 'Honda'
AND         dbo.countproject.model_name = 'Civic'
AND         dbo.countproject.type       = 'Sale'
AND         dbo.countproject.trans_type LIKE '%%EU'
AND         dbo.countproject.mfr        = '2000'
GROUP BY    YEAR(dbo.countproject.trans_date)
        ,   MONTH(dbo.countproject.trans_date)
ORDER BY    YEAR(dbo.countproject.trans_date)
```

The query returns the following result set:

```
| TransYear | TransMonth | TransNum |
|-----------|------------|----------|
|  2004     |     1      |     5    |
|  2004     |     3      |     1    |
|  2005     |     4      |     2    |
```

and so forth....

I am trying to get it to show all the months and years even if the value is NULL.

I tried creating a new table which will have the year and the month as columns to get it to join somehow, but I am lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What field specifically is nullable?  the `trans_date` field or something else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/tsql-generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2005 or above`, you could use `Common Table Expressions (CTE)` to get the desired result. Below example shows how you can fetch the results as you had described in the question.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d091b/1)

*Description*:

- Create and insert statements create the table and populates with some sample data. I have created the table based on the query provided in the question.
- The statement within the WITH clause is executing a recursive expression. In this case the `SELECT` above the `UNION ALL` fetches the minimum and maximum dates available in the table *dbo.countproject*
- Once the minimum date is fetched, the second SELECT statement after the UNION ALL increments the date in 1 month intervals until the recursive expression reaches the maximum date available in the table.
- The recursive CTE has produced all the available dates possible. This output is available in the table named *alltransactions*.
- We have to join this CTE output `alltransactions` with the actual table `countproject` using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` since we want to show all years and months even if there are no transactions.
- The tables `alltransactions` and `countproject` are joined on the *year* and *month* parts of the date. The query then applies the necessary filters in the *WHERE* clause and then groups the data by year and month before ordering it by year and month.
- You can notice from the sample data that the earliest date in the table is `2004-07-01` and the latest date is `2005-12-01`. Hence the output shows from year 2004 / month 07 till year 2005 / month 12.

Hope that helps.

*Script*:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.countproject
(   
        id          INT         NOT NULL IDENTITY
    ,   trans_date  DATETIME    NOT NULL
    ,   make_name   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   model_name  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   type        VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   trans_type  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,   mfr         INT         NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.countproject (trans_date, make_name, model_name, type, trans_type, mfr) VALUES
    ('1900-01-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('1900-01-01', 'Toyota',    'Corolla',  'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2004-07-01', 'Nissan',    'Altima',   'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2005-12-01', 'Toyota',    'Camry',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2004-04-01', 'Ford',      'Focus',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2005-08-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2005-11-01', 'Toyota',    'Camry',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2004-08-01', 'Toyota',    'Corolla',  'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2005-12-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2004-07-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2004-11-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000),
    ('2005-08-01', 'Honda',     'Civic',    'Sale', 'EU', 2000);


;WITH alltransactions
AS
(
    SELECT      MIN(trans_date) AS continuousdate
            ,   MAX(trans_date) AS maximumdate
    FROM        dbo.countproject
    WHERE           trans_date <> '1900-01-01'
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT      DATEADD(MONTH, 1, continuousdate) AS continuousdate
            ,   maximumdate
    FROM        alltransactions
    WHERE       DATEADD(MONTH, 1, continuousdate) <= maximumdate
)
SELECT          YEAR(at.continuousdate)     AS [Year]
            ,   MONTH(at.continuousdate)    AS [Month]

            ,   COUNT(cp.trans_date)        AS [Count]
FROM            alltransactions at
LEFT OUTER JOIN countproject    cp
ON              YEAR(at.continuousdate)     = YEAR(cp.trans_date)
AND             MONTH(at.continuousdate)    = MONTH(cp.trans_date)
AND             cp.make_name                = 'Honda'
and             cp.model_name               = 'Civic'
and             cp.type                     = 'Sale'
and             cp.trans_type               LIKE '%EU'
and             cp.mfr                      = '2000'
GROUP BY        YEAR(at.continuousdate)
            ,   MONTH(at.continuousdate)
ORDER BY        [Year]
            ,   [Month];
```

*Output*:

```
Year   Month  Count
-----  ------ -----
2004      4     0
2004      5     0
2004      6     0
2004      7     1
2004      8     0
2004      9     0
2004     10     0
2004     11     1
2004     12     0
2005      1     0
2005      2     0
2005      3     0
2005      4     1
2005      5     0
2005      6     0
2005      7     0
2005      8     2
2005      9     0
2005     10     0
2005     11     0
2005     12     1
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. To further complicate this...... Is there anyway I can cut out years 1900-1989 from the query as I have a list of 1356 rows. I think in the future I would also like to pivot the table somehow so that I can do all make names as rows and year of manufacture in columns. I am going to do some reading on that now. Once again thanks for your help!

Comment: yes my fault.. I realized I used the wrong field in the where close so it was not pulling any values.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN!

Here is an easy sample: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

You should get it done by yourself.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Alas, the SQL statement can only return the data in the table.  If you want all months, you need either a table with the year/month combinations you are intererested in or, preferably, a calendar table with all days and information about them.

With a calendar table, your query have a from clause that looked like:

```
from 
(
   select distinct year(date) as yr, month(date) as mon
   from calendar c
   where date between <earliest> and <latest>
) c 
left outer join CountTable ct
  on c.yr = year(ct.trans_date) 
  and c.mon = month(ct.trans_date)
```