# Logic to select available resources

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been banging my head up against a wall over this for a couple of hours now.

I'm working on a resource scheduling system for my company. I'm trying to come up with a SQL query that will allow me to figure out when a resource is available for an event.

I think the best way to describe this is with an example so here goes:

Given table `Availability` with a start and end date

```
TABLE Availability
| id   | resourceId | startDate  | endDate    |
| 100  | 10000      | 2014-04-15 | 2014-05-31 |
| 101  | 10001      | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-04 |
| 102  | 10001      | 2014-05-05 | 2014-05-10 |
| 103  | 10002      | 2014-04-05 | 2014-05-05 |
| 104  | 10002      | 2014-05-07 | 2014-05-31 |
```

And give that I need to find all resources that are available from `2014-05-04 - 2014-05-07`

With the given data, the total number of available resources is 2.

Resource `10000` is available obviously because its start and end dates span the needed range.

Resource `10001` is available because it has two entries that end and then begin on consecutive days.

Resource `10002` is NOT available because there is a gap in its availability on 2014-05-06.

Arriving at `10000` being available is easy because the simple query `SELECT * FROM availability WHERE startDate <= '2014-05-04' AND endDate >= '2014-05-07'` will yield the desired result.

Where I'm having trouble is how to have `10001` included and `10002` excluded. If I select all records where `2014-05-04` is `BETWEEN starTDate AND endDate` OR `2014-05-07` is `BETWEEN startDate and endDate` I end up with both rows for `10001` and `10002` returned. Can I compare these two rows in a single query so that I can see that there is a gap between the end and start dates of `10002` but there isn't one for `10001`?

**update**
I should have said I'm looking for a total count of available resources with this. And, as requested, here is a sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7035b/2

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: doesn't seem to lend itself well to a single SELECT statement; for each resource you will need to loop through the available date ranges, consolidating overlapping or adjacent entries, to build a true picture of availability. One thought, if the granularity is date rather than time, and the constraints are right, you could check (in your example) resources that were available on 5-04 and 5-05 and 5-06 and 5-07 and each of those is a simple query... then join the results together.

Comment: Ares you able to record when the resources are _not_ available, instead of when they _are_ available? _I.e._ are they permanently available unless reserved?  If so the problem will be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single query that uses RobP's idea.  Verified it to work for the example scenario.

```
WITH dates AS (
     SELECT CAST('2014-05-04' AS DATETIME) 'date'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, t.date) 
       FROM dates t
      WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, t.date) <= '2014-05-07')
SELECT resourceid
FROM availability, dates d
WHERE d.date >= startdate and d.date <= enddate
GROUP BY resourceid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= DATEDIFF("d",'2014-05-04','2014-05-07')+1
```

Got the idea about iterating through dates from [Generate a resultset of incrementing dates in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql)

Comment: By the way, I tested the above on SQL Server 2008 R2.  You may need to find equivalent DATEADD function or WITH construct for MySQL