# Join/UNION ALL to show result in different columns

Tags: sql-server

I am fetching COUNT from 3 different table based on some conditions but to group them on time interval. (Like: 1 hour, 30 minutes.)

I need the following output:

```
Date            Interval    Success Un-Success  Closed  CLInotFound
2/20/2016   01:01 – 02:00   5          3           2    13
2/20/2016   02:01 – 03:00   14         9          23    5
2/20/2016   03:01 – 04:00   8         67          89    345
2/20/2016   04:01 – 05:00   2         23          92    12
2/20/2016   05:01 – 06:00   44        55          78    98
2/20/2016   06:01 – 07:00   12        87          56    445
```

I am able to calculate them separately but when I am trying to combine the result gets different.

**Query 1 For Success & Un-Success:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), A.InsertionDate ,108) AS 'Interval',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.call_result = 0 then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Success',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN A.call_result = 1 then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Un-Success'
from dbo.AutoRectifier A 
WHERE CONVERT(DateTime,A.InsertionDate,101) BETWEEN '2016-02-19 02:10:35.000' AND '2016-02-19 07:15:35.000'
GROUP BY A.InsertionDate;
```

**Query 2 For Closed:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), C.DateAdded ,108) AS 'Interval',
 COUNT(*) AS 'Closed' FROM dbo.ChangeTicketState C 
WHERE C.SourceFlag = 'S-CNR' AND C.RET LIKE '%CLOSE%' 
AND C.DateAdded BETWEEN '2016-02-19 02:10:35.000' AND '2016-02-19 07:15:35.000'
GROUP BY C.DateAdded;
```

**Query 3 For CLI Not Found:**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), T.DateAdded ,108) AS 'Interval',
        COUNT(*) 'CLI Not Found' FROM dbo.TICKET_INFO T
     WHERE T.CONTACT_NUMBER = '' AND T.DateAdded BETWEEN '2016-02-19 02:10:35.000' AND '2016-02-19 07:15:35.000'
     GROUP BY T.DateAdded;
```

Comment: `Join` and `Union` are 2 entirely different things. What you need? Also, how are you combining the `results`? Add that query here as well.

Comment: Dear I only need the **Output** either Join/Union or Temporary table/Stored Procedure.  Need **OutPut**.
Thank you

Comment: Actually you are not getting any _intervals_ in your partial `select` statements

Comment: Yes, Dear but I need the above. Currently it only return **time** and **count**.

Comment: You may try to build intervals with another subquery via ROW_NUMBER and then refer it as a master dataset with your partial selects.

Comment: Ivan thank you for interest can you please help me with this? or if you have any example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824831/generate-dates-between-date-ranges, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got several problems to solve in you question.

1. You have to produce a union result set from Query1, Query2, Query3 to group it. You can use `UNION ALL` for it but all 3 queries must have similar column list for it. So, add
   `0 as Closed, 0 as CLInotFound` 
   to select-list of the Query1,
   add
   `0 as Success, 0 as Un-Success, 0 as CLInotFound`
   to select-list of the Query2 and add
   `0 as Success, 0 as Un-Success, 0 as Closed`
   to Query3
   Then you can write
   `select * from Query1 
   union all
   select * from Query2
   union all
   select * from Query3`
2. Don't convert date to varchar at Query1, Query2, Query3. Better return datetime from query to use it for grouping after union. So, query 1 will look like
   `SELECT A.InsertionDate AS Date, ...`
   Query2 -
   `SELECT C.DateAdded AS Date, ...`
   etc.
3. Then you can group results on per-hour basis, for instance using `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Date ,120), 1, 13)`

So, the result will look like
    `SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Date ,120), 1, 13) as Interval,
    sum(Success) as
    sum(Un-Success) as,
    sum(Closed) as,
    sum(CLInotFound) as
    from (
    select * from Query1
    union all
    select * from Query2
    union all
    select * from Query3
    ) q
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Date ,120), 1, 13)`

Its result have slightly different format of Date and Interval field, but shows the idea.
You can use `GROUP BY DATEPART(yy, Date), DATEPART(mm, Date), DATEPART(dd, Date), DATEPART(hh, Date)` instead of `GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Date ,120), 1, 13)` and format if as you wish.

Also result set does not contain intervals that not present at original data.
You can add Query4, containing all intervals required and zeros at all fields to fix it.

Comment: You are great (Y) Thank you for your response the query is now working perfect now all I need is Interval.

Comment: Importent: 3 queries must have similar order of columns! Othervise data from different colums will be mixed in results of union, because query results are united by column positions, not column names.

Comment: Yes, I tried the result was incorrect then I ordered the columns accordingly and it is working perfect.