# I want that procedure to insert the next dates for every 3 months in plsql

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I want that procedure to insert the next dates eg today is 1 jan 2016 I want to add 3 months to 1st jan 2016 and store the new dates in a table till end date 1-Feb-2017

startdate:1-01-2016
next date:1-04-2016,1-07-2016,1-10-2016,1-01-2017
enddate:1-Feb-2017

Comment: Have you tried googling for this? There are a *lot* of results on how to generate a date range, and a lot of duplicate questions for each of the databases you tagged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a resultset of incrementing dates in TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql)

Comment: Why tag spam? In your question title you say plsql and then proceed to add a tag for every known sql database engine?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that will get you going:

```
select add_months(to_date('01012016', 'DDMMYYYY'),  level - 1)
from dual
connect by add_months(to_date('01012016', 'DDMMYYYY'),  level - 1) <= to_date('01022017', 'DDMMYYYY');
```