# Temporary variable in UTC Time in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to convert a temporary variable into `UTC` time and print it using the following,

```
declare @dt datetime, @dtEnd datetime
set @dt = '2017-04-25' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
set @dtEnd = '2017-04-30' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 

select dateadd(day, number, @dt)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd
```

I got this code from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql).
I am getting an error,

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of AT TIME ZONE
>   function.

I am using SQL Server [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) to convert from `CDT` to `UTC`. Linked answer works great to just print without `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

How can I convert a temporary variable to print in `UTC` time?

Comment: `set @dt = convert(datetime,'2017-04-25') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' `

Comment: `set @dt = convert(datetime,'2017-04-25') at time zone 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` from CDT to UTC

Comment: @AlexKudryashev magic, that works! Post it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: There is good article on the item: https://sqlperformance.com/2016/07/sql-plan/at-time-zone

Comment: @AlexKudryashev thanks for that link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use cast as datetime

```
declare @dt datetime, @dtEnd datetime
set @dt = CAST('2017-04-25' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
set @dtEnd = CAST('2017-04-30' AS DATETIME) AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 

select dateadd(day, number, @dt)
from 
    (select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where name is null
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd
```

Comment: You're right casting works, but for my scenario, I edited it to use `at time zone 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.