# How to remove saturday and sunday in a month in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
for example:
--fromdate         todate
--2020/10/1       2020/11/01
```

Output should be like:

```
--Days           dayname
-------       ---------------
--2020/10/1  Monday
     ..        ..
```

Comment: Could you provide the query and/or data for which you want to apply the filter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the `WEEKDAY` and filter by it:

```
DATENAME ( WEEKDAY , my_date )
```

Something like this (the code for generating days is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479004/1080354))

```
declare @dt datetime, @dtEnd datetime
set @dt = '2020/10/1' 
set @dtEnd = '2020/11/01'

select dateadd(day, number, @dt)
       ,DATENAME ( WEEKDAY , dateadd(day, number, @dt) )
from 
    (select number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where [type] = 'P'
    ) n
where dateadd(day, number, @dt) < @dtEnd
    AND DATENAME ( WEEKDAY , dateadd(day, number, @dt) )  NOT IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

Comment: why we used  this  (select number from master.dbo.spt_values
     where [type] = 'P'
    ) n

Comment: @Kartheek It's just an example of generating dates in range. I guess you have such code. The important stuff is to use `DATENAME` to exclude the weekends.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query works well.

```
declare @result table
(
    Days varchar(10),
    DayName varchar(20)
)
declare @fromDate date = '2020/10/01'
declare @toDate date = '2020/11/01'

while @fromDate <= @toDate
begin
    if DATENAME(weekday, @fromDate) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
    begin
        insert into @result(Days, DayName)
        values(@fromDate, DATENAME(weekday, @fromDate))
    end
    set @fromDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @fromDate)
end
select *
from @result
```