# Query with empty rows as NULL SQL Server / SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I need to produce a result including non existent rows for a specific timestamp (in a column value). I have two variables for the start and end dates of the period to consult.

**Records table**:

```sql
SELECT record_at, sensor_value
FROM SomeTable
WHERE record_at BETWEEN '2021-03-12 18:01:00' AND '2021-03-12 18:05:00'
```

| record_at | sensor_value |
| --- | --- |
| '2021-03-12 18:01:00' | 123 |
| '2021-03-12 18:02:00' | 200 |
| '2021-03-12 18:03:00' | 400 |
| '2021-03-12 18:05:00' | 10 |

I need a query to adding that empty row at 18:04:00 in this case.

**Expected query result**:

| record_at | sensor_value |
| --- | --- |
| '2021-03-12 18:01:00' | 123 |
| '2021-03-12 18:02:00' | 200 |
| '2021-03-12 18:03:00' | 400 |
| **'2021-03-12 18:04:00'** | **NULL** |
| '2021-03-12 18:05:00' | 10 |

If no rows are available same approach:

| record_at | sensor_value |
| --- | --- |
| '2025-08-11 16:06:00' | NULL |
| '2025-08-11 16:07:00' | NULL |
| '2025-08-11 16:08:00' | NULL |
| '2025-08-11 16:09:00' | NULL |
| '2025-08-11 16:10:00' | NULL |

I can't use `master..spt_values`. Not supported in this version of SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The following post shows an answer that describes how to generate a JOIN table with your timestamps WITHOUT the use of `master..spt_values` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql)  See the (non-accepted) answer from @OMGPonies with around 45 upvotes -- it starts with "Tthe following uses a recursive CTE (SQL Server 2005+)"