# Split concatenated field into separate parts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, function

Using SQL Server 2008, I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor) post regarding splitting a concatenated field into separate parts for normalization purposes.

The problem with the solutions in the linked post is that they only work for delimited values.

The data I am attempting to split would be similar to:

UserID -- ConcatField
1 -- ABC
2 -- DEF

I would want the output to be like:

UserID -- ConcatField
1 -- A
1 -- B
1 -- C
2 -- D
2 -- E
2 -- F

Is there a function to split out these values without the use of a delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
WITH X AS
(
SELECT 1 AS UserID,'ABC' AS ConcatField UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS UserID,'DEF' AS ConcatField
), N AS
     (SELECT 1 i
     UNION ALL
     SELECT i+1
     FROM   N
     WHERE  i<1000 /*Or whatever your max string length is*/
     )

SELECT UserID,SUBSTRING(ConcatField,i,1) as ConcatField
 INTO #NewTemporaryTable
 FROM X JOIN N  ON I<= LEN(ConcatField)
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Gives

```
UserID      ConcatField
----------- -----------
1           A
1           B
1           C
2           D
2           E
2           F
```

**Edit:** Though as Jeff Moden points out in the comments the performance of recursive CTEs is far from great so you would be best off creating a permanent numbers table using one of the techniques [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232) and then using

```
SELECT  UserID ,
        SUBSTRING(ConcatField, i, 1) AS ConcatField
INTO    #NewTemporaryTable
FROM    YourTable
        JOIN Numbers ON Number <= LEN(ConcatField)
```

Comment: Follow up question: how would I go about inserting the results into a table?

Comment: a new table or an existing table?

Comment: A new, temporary table... same structure: UserID, ConcatField

Comment: Before we call this one "perfect", please see the following article for why you should NEVER use recursive CTE's for such a thing.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Moden has an excellent article on Tally Tables at SQL Server Central, which includes a section on splitting out strings like this. The second article listed below is a more in-depth look at strings using the Tally Table.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/70738/

(Free subscription required)

Answer (score 0):

Review the available string functions in TSQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx

After loading the raw data in a table, you can separate them relatively easily using the following functions:
* CHARINDEX
* SUBSTRING
* LEN
* LEFT & RIGHT

The actual implementation will of course depend on the data itself, but after splitting the records (maybe by processing them multiple times, first extracting C, then B, then A from 1 -- ABC), you should be good to go.