# Distinct random time generation in the fixed interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, random-time-generation

I'm trying to generate a random time between 8:00 AM and 8:00 PM *for each row* that is selected from a data set, however, I always get the ***same*** random value for each row – I want it to be ***different*** for each row.

*Table schema & data:*

```
╔══════╦════════════════╗
║  ID  ║  CREATED_DATE  ║
╠══════╬════════════════╣
║ ID/1 ║   26/04/2014   ║
║ ID/2 ║   26/04/2014   ║
║ ID/3 ║   26/04/2014   ║
║ ID/4 ║   26/04/2014   ║
║ ID/5 ║   26/04/2014   ║
╚══════╩════════════════╝
```

*Сurrent SQL statement:*

```sql
SELECT [ID]
     , MyFunction.dbo.AddWorkDays(14, [CREATED_DATE]) AS [New Date]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, CAST(43200000 * RAND() AS INT), CONVERT(TIME, '08:00')), 114) AS [New Time]
FROM [RandomTable]
```

*Current results (**same** time for each row in the `[New Time]` column):*

```
╔══════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║  ID  ║    New Date    ║    New Time    ║
╠══════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ ID/1 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
║ ID/2 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
║ ID/3 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
║ ID/4 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
║ ID/5 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
╚══════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

*Desired results (**different** time for each row in the `[New Time]` column):*

```
╔══════╦════════════════╦════════════════╗
║  ID  ║    New Date    ║    New Time    ║
╠══════╬════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ ID/1 ║   10/05/2014   ║    09:41:43    ║
║ ID/2 ║   10/05/2014   ║    15:05:23    ║
║ ID/3 ║   10/05/2014   ║    10:01:05    ║
║ ID/4 ║   10/05/2014   ║    19:32:45    ║
║ ID/5 ║   10/05/2014   ║    08:43:15    ║
╚══════╩════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? All of the above is just sample data – my real table has around 2800 records (*not sure if that will make a difference to anyone's suggestions*).

Comment: I think you need to LOOP it to generate different results.

Comment: Might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362048/generate-random-sql-server-2008-time-test-data

Comment: [RAND() and other runtime constant functions, redux](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/rand-and-other-runtime-constant-functions-redux/)

Comment: I see the suggestion about using a loop to insert the records, but I'm  not sure about how to do it :/

Comment: How does the current answer _not_ work @notulysses

Comment: @Ben : I don't know, but as the answer is not accepted since April, I guess it doesn't fit the needs, maybe it is too slow or whatever. I tried to get a feedback from OP, but it didn't work out, so you can address the question to him as well. There were 2 reasons for giving a bounty on this question: 1) It hasn't received much attention in the first place, so I think it is a shame as I didn't find anything this similar on this very network.2) I am looking for a better approach(es) to achieve the same goal, as I am not that familiar with SQL Server as with other RDBMS I was working with.

Comment: I've just seen you were the person who answered this. I'm not a little confused but go for it I guess. I don't think you're going to get any better than your answer to be honest :-).

Comment: @AMC did the answer posted in April not help you, if not what were your issues that required you to post a bounty?

Comment: @notulysses I realize that you are not the OP and so might have slightly different requirements, but: 1) is it ok to have collisions on the time for the same date?, and 2) can it be assumed that there will be an INT or BIGINT `IDENTITY` field on the table?

Comment: @srutzky: Maybe we are on the same page here: I've already thought about the second condition: instead of generating one we can use an actual unique `ID` [somehow](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84dc3/10). As for the first one : I guess it would be just a matter of the data amount for one day, if it greater than _86400_ then it is just something to deal with. So, answering your question: yes, you can use your own requirements in your answer, just post it with a caveat.

Comment: @notulysses, I thought of something like `RAND(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeID))` or simply `RAND(SomeID)`. It does produce different results for each row, but they are not random as expected. For my system `RAND(1) = 0.713591993212924`, `RAND(2) = 0.713610626184182`, `RAND(3) = 0.713629259155440`, etc. When you see results it becomes obvious why this approach can't work with the algorithm that T-SQL `RAND` implements. Luckily I found that since 2008 there is a function that does exactly what we need: `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`. See my answer for details.

Comment: @notulysses Not sure if you got the notification, but I set up a chat room to discuss: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68920/discuss-intent-of-how-to-generate-different-random-time

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Interpretation of Original Question:

The question states:

- Generate a *random* time between 8:00 AM and 8:00 PM (i.e. a 12-hour window)
- It should be different *for each row* (i.e. unique across all rows)
- The real table has around 2800 records

Now factor in the following points:

- Sample data shows only a single date
- There are 86,400 seconds in 24 hours, hence 43,200 seconds in 12 hours

There is some ambiguity in the following areas:

- What exactly is random within the context of "different *for every row*", given that truly random values cannot be guaranteed to be different for every row. In fact, *truly* random numbers *could* theoretically be the *same* for every row. So is the emphasis on "random" or "different"? Or are we really talking about different but not sequentially ordered (to give the appearance of randomness without actually being random)?
- What if there are ever more than 2800 rows? What if there are 1 million rows?
- If there can be more than 43,200 rows, how to handle "different *for each row*" (since it is not possible to have unique across all rows)?
- Will the date ever vary? If so, are we really talking about "different for each row *per date*"?
- If "different for each row *per date*":

  - Can the times for each date follow the same, non-sequential pattern? Or does the pattern need to differ per each date?
  - Will there ever be more than 43,200 rows for any particular date? If so, the times can only be unique *per each set of 43,200 rows*.

Given the information above, there are a few ways to interpret the request:

1. **Emphasis on "random":** Dates and number of rows don't matter. Generate truly random times that are highly likely, but not *guaranteed*, to be unique using one of the three methods shown in the other answers:

   - @notulysses: `RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) * 43200`
   - @Steve Ford: `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 43201)`
   - @Vladimir Baranov : `CAST(43200000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) as int)`
2. **Emphasis on "different for each row", always <= 43,200 rows:** If the number of rows never exceeds the number of available seconds, it is easy to guarantee unique times across all rows, regardless of same or different dates, and appear to be randomly ordered.
3. **Emphasis on "different for each row", could be > 43,200 rows:** If the number of rows can exceed the number of available seconds, then it is not possible to guarantee uniqueness across *all* rows, but it would be possible to still guarantee uniqueness across rows of any particular date, provided that no particular date has > 43,200 rows.

Hence, I based my answer on the idea that:

- Even if the number of rows for the O.P. never exceeds 2800, it is more likely that most others who are encountering a similar need for randomness would have a larger data set to work with (i.e. there could easily be 1 million rows, for any number of dates: 1, 5000, etc.)
- Either the sample data is overly simplistic in using the same date for all 5 rows, or even if the date is the same for all rows in this particular case, in most other cases that is less likely to happen
- Uniqueness is to be favored over Randomness
- If there is a pattern to the "seemingly random" ordering of the seconds for each date, there should at least be a varying offset to the start of the sequence across the dates (when the dates are ordered sequentially) to give the appearance of randomness between any small grouping of dates.

---

### Answer:

If the situation requires unique times, that cannot be guaranteed with any method of generating truly random values. I really like the use of `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` by @Vladimir Baranov, but it is nearly impossible to get a unique set of values generated:

```sql
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO @Table (Col1)
    SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))
    FROM [master].sys.objects so
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so2
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so3;
    -- 753,571 rows
```

Increasing the random value to 8 bytes does seem to work:

```sql
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO @Table (Col1)
    SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8))
    FROM [master].sys.objects so
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so2
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so3;
    -- 753,571 rows
```

Of course, if we are generating down to the second, then there are only 86,400 of those. Reducing the scope seems to help as the following does occasionally work:

```sql
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col1 BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO @Table (Col1)
    SELECT TOP (86400) CONVERT(BIGINT, CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))
    FROM [master].sys.objects so
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so2
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.objects so3;
```

However, things get a bit trickier if the uniqueness needs *per each day* (which seems like a reasonable requirement of this type of project, as opposed to unique across all days). But a random number generator isn't going to know to reset at each new day.

If it is acceptable to merely have the appearance of being random, then we can guarantee uniqueness per each date without:

- looping / cursor constructs
- saving already used values in a table
- using `RAND()`, `NEWID()`, or `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()`

The following solution uses the concept of [Modular Multiplicative Inverses](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/12/math-from-scratch-part-thirteen-multiplicative-inverses/) (MMI) which I learned about in this answer: [generate seemingly random unique numeric ID in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967215/generate-seemingly-random-unique-numeric-id-in-sql-server) . Of course, that question did not have a tightly-defined range of values like we have here with only 86,400 of them per day. So, I used a range of 86400 (as "Modulo") and tried a few "coprime" values (as "Integer") in an [online calculator](http://planetcalc.com/3311/) to get their MMIs:

- 13 (MMI = 39877)
- 37 (MMI = 51373)
- 59 (MMI = 39539)

I use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a CTE, partitioned (i.e. grouped) by `CREATED_DATE` as a means of assigning each second of the day a value.

But, while the values generated for seconds 0, 1, 2, ... and so on sequentially will appear random, across different days that particular second will map to the same value. So, the second CTE (named "WhichSecond") shifts the starting point for each date by converting the date to an INT (which converts dates to a sequential offset from 1900-01-01) and then multiply by 101.

```sql
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
  CREATED_DATE DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2014-10-05');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2014-10-05');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2014-10-05');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2014-10-05');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2014-10-05');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2015-03-15');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2016-10-22');
INSERT INTO @Data (CREATED_DATE) VALUES ('2015-03-15');

;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT tmp.ID,
         CONVERT(DATETIME, tmp.CREATED_DATE) AS [CREATED_DATE],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tmp.CREATED_DATE ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
                      AS [RowNum]
  FROM   @Data tmp
), WhichSecond AS
(
  SELECT cte.ID,
         cte.CREATED_DATE,
         ((CONVERT(INT, cte.[CREATED_DATE]) - 29219) * 101) + cte.[RowNum]
                      AS [ThisSecond]
  FROM   cte
)
SELECT parts.*,
       (parts.ThisSecond % 86400) AS [NormalizedSecond], -- wrap around to 0 when
                                                         -- value goes above 86,400
       ((parts.ThisSecond % 86400) * 39539) % 86400 AS [ActualSecond],
       DATEADD(
                 SECOND,
                 (((parts.ThisSecond % 86400) * 39539) % 86400),
                 parts.CREATED_DATE
              ) AS [DateWithUniqueTime]
FROM WhichSecond parts
ORDER BY parts.ID;
```

Returns:

```
ID  CREATED_DATE  ThisSecond  NormalizedSecond  ActualSecond  DateWithUniqueTime
1   2014-10-05    1282297     72697             11483         2014-10-05 03:11:23.000
2   2014-10-05    1282298     72698             51022         2014-10-05 14:10:22.000
3   2014-10-05    1282299     72699              4161         2014-10-05 01:09:21.000
4   2014-10-05    1282300     72700             43700         2014-10-05 12:08:20.000
5   2014-10-05    1282301     72701             83239         2014-10-05 23:07:19.000
6   2015-03-15    1298558      2558             52762         2015-03-15 14:39:22.000
7   2016-10-22    1357845     61845             83055         2016-10-22 23:04:15.000
8   2015-03-15    1298559      2559              5901         2015-03-15 01:38:21.000
```

---

If we want to only generate times between 8:00 AM and 8:00 PM, we only need to make a few minor adjustments:

1. Change the range (as "Modulo") from 86400 to half of it: 43200
2. Recalculate the MMI (can use the same "coprime" values as "Integer"): 39539 (same as before)
3. Add `28800` to the second parameter of the `DATEADD` as an 8 hour offset

The result will be a change to just one line (since the others are diagnostic):

```sql
-- second parameter of the DATEADD() call
28800 + (((parts.ThisSecond % 43200) * 39539) % 43200)
```

---

Another means of shifting each day in a less predictable fashion would be to make use of `RAND()` by passing in the INT form of `CREATED_DATE` in the "WhichSecond" CTE. This would give a stable offset per each date since `RAND(x)` will return the same value `y` for the same value of `x` passed in, but will return a different value `y` for a different value of `x` passed in. Meaning:

RAND(1) = y1
RAND(2) = y2
RAND(3) = y3
RAND(2) = y2

The second time `RAND(2)` was called, it still returned the same value of `y2` that it returned the first time it was called.

Hence, the "WhichSecond" CTE could be:

```
(
  SELECT cte.ID,
         cte.CREATED_DATE,
         (RAND(CONVERT(INT, cte.[CREATED_DATE])) * {some number}) + cte.[RowNum]
                      AS [ThisSecond]
  FROM   cte
)
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that it is possible to use something like `RAND(CHECKSUM(HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS varbinary(4)))))` to generate a sequence of unique random numbers. I've added this method to my answer to the list of all methods. The main idea is that we supply the seed to `RAND` function and we control what this seed is. If the supplied seeds are unique, then `RAND` will transform them to unique random numbers. `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` may behave similarly and you don't need CHECKSUM to reduce result of HASHBYTES to int.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Interesting. The idea has promise. Please see the note I left on your answer as that seemed a better place to leave it. And I wasn't being negative, just pointing out the two issues.

Comment: After reading your chat with @notulysses I finally understood why you were looking specifically for unique random numbers. It never occurred to me to interpret the original question in this way. I added to my answer that I think it is similar to shuffling the set of (unique) values.

Comment: Great answer. Even though I used a different solution to solve the issue I had at the time, this is the best answer I've received thus far. Anyone reading this should also check out the answer from @VladimirBaranov.

Answer (score 29):

The issue *OP* had while using just `rand()` is due to it's evaluation *once per query*.

*From the [**documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx):*

> If *seed* is not specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a *seed* value at random. For a specified *seed* value, the result returned is always the same.

Approach that is described below removes optimization and suppresses this behavior, so `rand()` is evaluated *once per row*:

```sql
dateadd( second
       , rand(cast(newid() as varbinary)) * 43200
       , cast('08:00:00' as time) )
```

- [`newid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms190348.aspx) generates unique value of type [`uniqueidentifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187942.aspx);
- the value is converted with `cast` to be used as *seed* in [`rand([seed])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177610.aspx) function to generate a pseudo-random `float` value from *0 through 1*, and as *seed* is always unique the returning value is unique too .

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84dc3/13)

Comment: The reason why `RAND()` alone does not work is that `RAND()` is a [runtime constant](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/rand-and-other-runtime-constant-functions-redux/) and as such is folded (evaluated only once *per query*). Adding the `NEWID()` removes the optimization and `RAND()` will be evaluated once *per row*.

Answer (score 16):

You could alternatively use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 43201), CAST('08:00:00' AS Time))
```

The  `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 43201)` generates a random number between `0` and `43200`. See [Discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42018)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATEADD(s, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()) % 43201), CAST('08:00:00' AS Time)) AS [RandomTime]
FROM 
( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
) Y(A)
CROSS JOIN
( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
) Z(A)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42018/0)**:

```
|    RANDOMTIME    |
|------------------|
| 16:51:58.0000000 |
| 10:42:44.0000000 |
| 14:01:38.0000000 |
| 13:33:51.0000000 |
| 18:00:51.0000000 |
| 11:29:03.0000000 |
| 10:21:14.0000000 |
| 16:38:27.0000000 |
| 09:55:37.0000000 |
| 13:21:13.0000000 |
| 11:29:37.0000000 |
| 10:57:49.0000000 |
| 14:56:42.0000000 |
| 15:33:11.0000000 |
| 18:49:45.0000000 |
| 16:23:28.0000000 |
| 09:00:05.0000000 |
| 09:20:01.0000000 |
| 11:26:23.0000000 |
| 15:26:23.0000000 |
| 10:38:44.0000000 |
| 11:46:30.0000000 |
| 16:00:59.0000000 |
| 09:29:18.0000000 |
| 09:09:19.0000000 |
```

Comment: @notulysses note I'm using CHECKSUM rather than RAND

Comment: I'm not [talking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that%27s+what+i%27m+talking+about) about the content of the answer - I'm just glad that there is another one with a different approach.

Comment: @notulysses oh I see, I hadn't noticed that the question was so old. Your answer should have been accepted when you posted it tbh

Answer (score 8):

There are several methods:

- Generate a table with random numbers in advance and use it whenever needed. Or take this data from [some reputable source](http://www.nist.gov/pml/wmd/pubs/upload/AppenB-HB133-05-Z.pdf).
- Various combinations that use [`NEWID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190348(v=sql.120).aspx) function to provide a seed for `RAND`. It should be used with caution, because there is no guarantee about distribution of NEWID values. One of the best methods to make it more or less uniformly distributed is via the `CHECKSUM`: `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`. The good thing about this method is that NEWID function is available since SQL Server 2000.
- Instead of `NEWID` use, say, MD5 of some column as a seed for `RAND`: `RAND(CHECKSUM(HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(SomeID AS varbinary(4)))))` Or simply row number: `RAND(CHECKSUM(HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS varbinary(4)))))`. This method is available since at least SQL Server 2005. The primary difference from `NEWID` method is that you have full control over the random sequence. You can't control what `NEWID` returns and you can't restart the random sequence from the same number again. If you supply same sets of, say, row numbers using `PARTITION BY` you'll get same sets of random numbers. It may be useful in the cases when you need to use the same sequence of random numbers several times. It is possible to get the same random number for two different seeds. I tested it for row numbers from 1 to 1,000,000. `MD5` of them are all different. `CHECKSUM` of `MD5` result in 122 collisions. `RAND` of this `CHECKSUM` result in 246 collisions. When tested with row numbers from 1 to 100,000 `CHECKSUM` had 1 collision, `RAND` had 3 collisions.
- Another possibility is to simply implement your own user-defined function in T-SQL that generates a random number using your preferred algorithm. In this case you have full control of everything. Usually pseudo random generators have to store their internal state between invocations, so you may end up with having a dedicated table that stores this data.
- You can write your user-defined function using CLR. In this case you can implement your own generator, or use functions built-into .NET, like [`Random` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).
- At last, since SQL Server 2008 there is a built-in function [`CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627408.aspx).

I will describe the last method in detail, because I think that it is a very good solution for SQL Server 2008 and above. `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` is called for each row of the result set, as opposed to `RAND`, which is called only once.

> CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM (Transact-SQL)
>
> Returns a cryptographic random number generated by the Crypto API
>   (CAPI). The output is a hexadecimal number of the specified number of
>   bytes.

Besides, `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` should provide much better random values, than `RAND`. Better in terms of distribution and crypto-strength. Example:

```
(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5)
```

This generates 4 random bytes as `varbinary`. We have to explicitly cast them to `int` first. Then result is transformed into a float number between 0 and 1.

So, the original query would like this:

```
SELECT ID AS [ID]
     , MyFunction.dbo.AddWorkDays(14, S.CREATED_DATE) AS [New Date]
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
     CAST(43200000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) as int),
     CONVERT(TIME, '08:00')), 114) AS [New Time]
FROM RandomTable
```

Here is a stand-alone example that is easy to copy-paste and try (I used the query from another answer by @Steve Ford):

```
SELECT DATEADD(millisecond, 
    CAST(43200000 * (CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) as int) / 4294967295.0 + 0.5) as int), 
    CAST('08:00:00' AS Time)) AS [RandomTime]
FROM 
    ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
    ) Y(A)
    CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
    ) Z(A)
```

This is the result:

```
RandomTime
10:58:24.7200000
19:40:06.7220000
11:04:29.0530000
08:57:31.6130000
15:03:14.9470000
09:15:34.9380000
13:46:43.1250000
11:27:00.8940000
14:42:23.6100000
15:07:56.2120000
11:39:09.8830000
08:16:44.3960000
14:23:38.4820000
17:28:31.7440000
16:29:31.4320000
09:09:15.0210000
12:31:09.8370000
11:23:09.8430000
15:35:45.5480000
17:42:49.3390000
08:07:05.4930000
18:17:16.2980000
11:49:08.2010000
10:20:21.7620000
15:56:58.6110000
```

### Addition

When I read the original question I didn't think that it is really necessary to ensure that all generated random numbers are unique.
I interpreted the word "different" in the question as a vague opposite to seeing the same number in each row of the result that you see when using a simple `SELECT RAND()`.
I think that in many cases it doesn't matter if there are few colliding random numbers. In many cases it would actually be the correct behavior.

So, my understanding is that when there is a need of a sequence of **unique** random numbers, it is in a sense equivalent to the following task. 
We have a set of some values/rows, for example, a set of unique IDs or all 86400 seconds of a day or 2800 rows for a given day.
We want to shuffle these values/rows. We want to rearrange these rows in a random order.

To shuffle the given set of rows we simply need to `ORDER BY` random numbers (these random numbers may have reasonable amount of collisions here). Random numbers could be generated by any method. Something like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ([optional PARTITION BY ...] ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4))
```

or literally

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4)
```

depending on where and how it is used.

Comment: Regarding your update related to `HASHBYTES('MD5', CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...) AS varbinary(4)))`: It would reset per each day if partitioning by the date, but it is not _guaranteed_ unique since there could be collisions when doing `CHECKSUM(HASHBYTES('MD5',...))`. Those collisions might never occur, so in practical sense it could be unique-ish, but still theoretically possible to not be unique, especially if there are close to 86400 or even 43200 entries for a given date. Also, without using an offset that varies by date, the same row num across all dates will be the same second.

Comment: @srutzky You are right. I removed the clause about random numbers being unique from the answer. I tested and confirmed that collisions indeed happen. So, the main point of this approach is an ease of control over the generated sequence. Using it would be easy to generate several identical sequences.

Comment: Of course truly random numbers are not necessarily unique, throw a die 6 times!

Answer (score 3):

Test this :

```
 Declare @t table(ID int,CREATED_DATE datetime)
insert into @t values
 (1 ,  '04/26/2014'),
 (2 ,  '04/26/2014'),
 (3 ,  '04/26/2014'),
 (4 ,  '04/26/2014')

 ;WITH CTE AS
 (
   SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(SECOND, RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) * 43200, 
   CAST('08:00:00' AS TIME)),114) AS [New Time] FROM @t WHERE ID=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *,CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(SECOND, RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) * 43200, 
   CAST('08:00:00' AS TIME)), 114)  FROM @t WHERE ID>1 AND ID<=5
 )
 SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option that gives you a bit more control over how the time is generated.
You can specify the interval between the random times.
It also doesn't make use of the `RAND` function.

```
DECLARE @StartTime  VARCHAR(10) = '08:00',
        @EndTime    VARCHAR(10) = '20:00',
        @Interval   INT = 5 --(In Seconds)

WITH times AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(TIME, @StartTime) AS t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, @Interval, t)
    FROM times
    WHERE t < @EndTime
)

SELECT *, 
(SELECT TOP 1 t FROM times WHERE d.Id > 0 ORDER BY NEWID())
FROM #data d
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

*On a side note :*
If you remove the `WHERE` clause in the subquery above (`WHERE d.Id > 0`), the same time value is returned for all the rows, i.e. the same problem that you started with

Answer (score 0):

All,

I thought I'd share the answer to my question. I can't remember exactly where I found the details - I think it was via one of the links provided by sgeddes.

I used the following query to get a random time between 8am and 7:55pm (roughly)

```
SELECT convert(varchar,CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(ms, dbo.MyRand(335 ,830) * 86400, 0), 114),114)
```

The MyRand function is below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myRand(@Min INT, @Max INT) RETURNS decimal(18,15) AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @BinaryFloat BINARY(8)
SELECT @BinaryFloat = CAST(Id AS BINARY) FROM vwGuid

DECLARE
@PartValue TINYINT,
@Mask TINYINT,
@Mantissa FLOAT,
@Exponent SMALLINT,
@Bit TINYINT,
@Ln2 FLOAT,
@BigValue BIGINT,
@RandomNumber FLOAT

SELECT
@Mantissa = 1,
@Bit = 1,
@Ln2 = LOG(2),
@BigValue = CAST(@BinaryFloat AS BIGINT),
@Exponent = (@BigValue & 0x7ff0000000000000) / EXP(52 * @Ln2)

WHILE @Part <= 8
BEGIN
SELECT
@PartValue = CAST(SUBSTRING(@BinaryFloat, @Part, 1) AS TINYINT),
@Mask =

WHILE @Mask > 0
BEGIN
IF @PartValue & @Mask > 0
SET @Mantissa = @Mantissa + EXP(-@Bit * @Ln2)

SELECT
@Mask = @Mask / 2
END
END

SET @RandomNumber = CASE @Exponent WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE CAST(@Exponent AS FLOAT) / 2047 END

RETURN CAST((@RandomNumber * (@Max - @Min)) + @Min AS DECIMAL(18,15))

END
GO
END
```

I hope this helps. I haven't read many of the replies above so apologies if someone has a better answer - this is simply how I solved it.

Thanks

Comment: What is `vwGuid` and `vwGuid.Id` in this user-defined function?

Comment: @AMC : If it is possible, please, elaborate your answer with details. In any case, I thought it might be a good idea asking you to pick the answer for a bounty offer with me as it is your question in the first place. Also, after the bounty expires, please, choose one of the answers as accepted to inform people, that would stuck with the same issue, that it is resolved.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov `vwGuid` is most likely a VIEW that simply does `SELECT NEWID() AS [Id];` as that is a method of working around the restriction of not being able to call `NEWID()` in a T-SQL function.

Comment: strutzky is correct. Simply use CREATE VIEW dbo.vwGuid AS
SELECT Id = NEWID()

Comment: @notulysses : I'll do that this evening. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Get Random Time in a given range: Sql Server](https://ssisdevelopers.wordpress.com/2013/04/01/get-random-time-in-a-given-range-sql-server/)

```
SELECT
    X.Value,
    RT.RandomTime,
    DateObject = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) + CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, RT.RandomTime)
 FROM (VALUES(101),(204),(77),(54),(75),(66)) X(Value)  /* YOUR TABLE */
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT FromTime = '08:20:00', ToTime = '08:33:00') FT
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT MaxSeconds = DATEDIFF(ss, FT.FromTime, FT.ToTime)) MS
 CROSS APPLY(SELECT RandomTime = CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(SECOND, (MS.MaxSeconds + 1) * RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY, NEWID() )) , FT.FromTime))) RT
```

[image]