# t-sql return multiple rows depending on field value

Tags: t-sql

i am trying to run an export on a system that only allows t-sql. i know enough of php to make a foreach loop, but i don't know enough of t-sql to generate multiple rows for a given quantity.
i need a result to make a list of items with "1 of 4" like data included in the result

given a table like

```
orderid, product, quantity
1000,ball,3
1001,bike,4
1002,hat,2
```

how do i get a select query result like:

> orderid, item_num, total_items,
> product
>
> 1000,1,3,ball
>
> 1000,2,3,ball
>
> 1000,3,3,ball
>
> 1001,1,4,bike
>
> 1001,2,4,bike
>
> 1001,3,4,bike
>
> 1001,4,4,bike
>
> 1002,1,2,hat
>
> 1002,2,2,hat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with the aid of an auxiliary numbers table.

```
;WITH T(orderid, product, quantity) AS
(
select 1000,'ball',3 union all
select 1001,'bike',4 union all
select 1002,'hat',2
)

SELECT orderid, number as item_num, quantity as total_items, product
FROM T
JOIN master..spt_values on number> 0 and number <= quantity
where type='P'
```

NB: The code above uses the `master..spt_values` table - this is just for demo purposes I suggest you create your own tally table using [one of the techniques here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232).

Comment: @Thomas - Yep. Every auxiliary numbers table will have some limit. @noob - This is just for demo purposes I suggest you create your own tally table using one of the techniques here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232

Comment: +1, but why not `number between 1 and quantity`? I mean, I'd like to know if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Andriy - I did already think about making that edit. I agree it's neater but hopefully the OP will be using a permanent tally table from `1..n` so they can completely drop the `number> 0` check in their actual query.

Comment: thank you everyone. I just learned a little bit more SQL and this solution solved my problem exactly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on SQL Server 2005 or later version, then you can try a recursive CTE instead of a tally table.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT orderid, 1 item_num, product, quantity
    FROM YourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT orderid, item_num+1, product, quantity
    FROM CTE
    WHERE item_num < quantity
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

I'm not on a computer with a database engine where I can test this, so let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, IF you know the maximum value for the # of products for any product (and it's not too big, say 4), you can:

- Create a helper table called Nums containing 1 integer column n, with rows containing 1,2,3,4
- Run

  ```
   SELECT * from Your_table, Nums
   WHERE  Nums.n <= Your_table.quantity
  ```

Comment: CROSS JOIN syntax would be nicer

Comment: not a biggy. Replace `,` operator in table list with `CROSS JOIN` operator. Both generate cartesian product.

Comment: @Thomas is there a difference?