# Adding a row value more than once to STDEV()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
| rowNumber | amount | count |
|    1      | 1000   |   2   |
|    2      | 1500   |   3   |
|    3      | 1750   |   3   |
|    4      | 2000   |   1   |
```

Now if I want to get the stdev how can I make the amount of the row 1 be inserted in the function's expression twice, the amount of the row 2 be inserted 3 times and so on... Right now each amount is inserted in a temp table the necessary times and we get the stdev from that table, but I want to see if there is a better and more efficient way to do so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join onto a [numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232)

```
SELECT STDEV(amount)
FROM YourTable JOIN Numbers ON N  <= YourTable.[count]
```

or write a custom CLR aggregate that takes both parameters and does the corresponding calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going with the numbers table approach.