# get multiple records from one record

Tags: sql-server

i have a table with 2 columns Name as string ,Qty as integer i need amount of each record X the Qty Field for example

```
Name   | Qty
-----------
Dave   | 25
Nathan | 10
Chaim  | 8
```

i need from Dave 25 records from nathan 10 and chaim 8

Comment: Does Dave have multiple rows in the table?  And you want to sum up the various Qty's?  It's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: @Steve "dave" is 1 record in the qty colum the value is 25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of the use case for this requirement but you can do this with the aid of a numbers table. I use `master..spt_values` below for demo purposes but you should create a permanent one using [one of the techniques in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232).

```
;WITH T(Name,Qty) AS
(
SELECT 'Dave',25 union all
SELECT 'Nathan',10 union all
SELECT 'Chaim',8
), Numbers AS
(
SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values 
WHERE   type='P' AND number > 0
)
SELECT Name
FROM T 
JOIN Numbers ON  number  <= Qty
```

Comment: but i don't know what the value in the Qty Field

Comment: @Nathan - You don't need to know. As long as you make sure that the Numbers table is at least as big as any conceivable value it might have (and you can enforce this with check constraints on `Qty`). You just join on `number  <= Qty`