# SQL I want to duplicate record on insert

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates, while-loop, record

Without using a while or forloop, is there a way to insert a record two or more times on a single insert?

Thanks

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ((VALUE,VALUE)
SELECT VALUE,VALUE FROM TABLE1 )) *  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to `CROSS JOIN` onto a table with 2 rows. The following would work in SQL Server.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ((VALUE,VALUE)

SELECT VALUE,VALUE 
FROM TABLE1, (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) T(C)
```

If you have an auxilliary numbers table you could also do

```
SELECT VALUE,VALUE 
FROM TABLE1 JOIN Numbers ON N <=2
```

Comment: Also could do `select value, value from table1 t1 union all select value, value from table1 t2 ...`.  This would have the advantage of possibly adding a filter to choose which records are inserted once and which records are inserted twice.

Comment: Good Point. Would mean the source table is scanned twice though.

Comment: Actually, couldn't you dynamically determine how many records to include via something liks `SELECT Value, Value FROM Table1 JOIN Numbers ON N <= Value`?

Comment: @mellamokb - Yes. As here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808083/get-multiple-records-from-one-record/5808148#5808148

Answer (score 1):

--first create a dummy table with 2 records

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 ((VALUE,VALUE)
SELECT VALUE,VALUE FROM TABLE1, dummytable ))
```

Comment: Union all does duplicate record, but its not dynamic. Sometimes the record may need to be duplicated 3 or 4 times. Maybe all I can really use is a while loop?

Comment: @user - You can use a numbers table as per the second suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant way, but could work easily.
If you have a table with an high enough number of records you can do the cross join with a TOP clause

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 
SELECT VALUE,VALUE FROM TABLE1 
cross join (select top 2 TABLE_DUMMY) as DUMMY
```

This works for MQ SqlServer, to let it work in other DBMS you should change the TOP with the keyword needed by your DBMS