# Getting the min and max year of a range of dates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

We have a date field in one of our tables and i need to create a filter from this column.  I need to get the min year and the max year and then populate the years between them.  I can easily create a stored proc that gets the min and max and then create a loop in my script to achieve this, but wondered if there is a better way to do this in sql.  I am using sql server 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a numbers/tally table. [SQL, Auxiliary table of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers)

Here is a sample using master..spt_values.

```
select number as [Year] 
from master..spt_values
where number between 2008 and 2011
  and type = 'P'
```

Result:

```
number
------
2008
2009
2010
2011
```

Just replace the values in the between clause with your min and max year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how [@Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008091/getting-the-min-and-max-year-of-a-range-of-dates/7008308#7008308)'s suggestion could be applied to your particular problem:

```
SELECT
  v.number AS Year
FROM master..spt_values v
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      YEAR(MIN(Date)) AS MinYear,
      YEAR(MAX(Date)) AS MaxYear
    FROM atable
  ) ON v.number BETWEEN MinYear AND MaxYear
WHERE v.type = 'P'
```