# Interesting SQL Join on dates between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, datetime, join

First off, thanks to anyone who helps me solve this problem. I am using SQL 2005, but can use 2008 if no solution is available in 05.

I have a rows of data that look like such:

```
select * from mySPtable

| myPK | Area | RequestType |  StartDate  |  EndDate  |
   1      SB        ADD        8/14/2011    8/18/2011
   2      NB        RMV        8/16/2011    8/16/2011
```

So what I want to do is count up the total requests for each area by day. Results should be:

```
|  myDate  | RequestType |  Area  | myCount |
  8/14/2011      ADD         SB        1
  8/15/2011      ADD         SB        1
  8/16/2011      ADD         SB        1
  8/16/2011      RMV         NB        1
  8/17/2011      ADD         SB        1
  8/18/2011      ADD         SB        1
```

How do I go about doing this? I'm stumped and no amount of googling has helped.

Comment: Does the first row (myPK == 1) imply a total of five requests, one per day?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need either a Calendar table or you can generate one with a CTE. Once you have that, the rest of the query should be fairly trivial. The CTE approach can be a little complex due to recursion issues and not being allowed to use aggregates, so below I've used a table variable. You can also make this a permanent table that you keep in your database.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (my_date DATETIME NOT NULL)
DECLARE @date DATETIME, @max_date DATETIME

SELECT @date = MIN(StartDate), @max_date = MAX(EndDate) FROM My_Table

WHILE (@date <= @max_date)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Calendar (my_date) VALUES (@date)
    SELECT @date = DATEADD(dy, 1, @date)
END

SELECT
    C.myDate,
    M.RequestType,
    M.Area,
    COUNT(*) AS myCount
FROM
    @Calendar C
INNER JOIN My_Table M ON
    M.StartDate <= C.myDate AND
    M.EndDate >= C.myDate
GROUP BY
    C.myDate,
    M.RequestType,
    M.Area
ORDER BY
    C.myDate,
    M.RequestType,
    M.Area
```

Depending on how large your potential date range is, filling the table variable could take awhile. For example, if the range spanned a decade or two.

Comment: would adding a table with all the dates not be easier and faster? instead of creating it at runtime?  btw nice solution...

Comment: That's how I would normally do it, and I did mention that you could make it a permanent table. I usually have a Calendar in my databases where I can also include things like is_holiday, is_weekday, financial_quarter, etc. to make a lot of queries easier.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you may want a ['Calendar' file](http://codeinet.blogspot.com/2006/08/auxiliary-calendar-table-for-sql.html).  Especially as part of a larger business organization, this will become extremely useful.

After generating the calendar, you can get your table with the following:

```
SELECT a.isoDate, b.RequestType, b.Area, count(*)
FROM calendar as a
JOIN mySPTable as b
ON a.isoDate between b.StartDate and b.EndDate
WHERE a.isoDate >= [input_start_date] 
      AND a.isoDate < [input_end_date]
GROUP BY a.isoDate, b.RequestType, b.Area
```

This will generate a row for every date in the calendar file that is between the start and end dates for at least one row of mySPTable.

As a side note, it's also possible to generate the range of dates with a recursive CTE, but especially over the long run, I'd recommend generating and using the calendar file.
Quick CTE:

```
WITH DateRange (thisDate) as (SELECT [input_start_date]
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT DATEADD(dy, 1, thisDate)
                              FROM DateRange
                              WHERE thisDate < [input_end_date])
```

Comment: I'm a fan of CTEs, but be aware there is a limit on the number of recursions.  The absolute limit is 32,767 and the default limit is 100.  See MAXRECURSION at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx.

Comment: I keep forgetting that SQL Server has that default - DB2 doesn't, and I think the limit is getting an out-of-memory error.  Of course, if you're running over more than about a year's worth of dates, you probably want an actual calendar file anyways...

Comment: Correction: Setting MAXRECURSION to zero disables any limit.  My bad.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a number table (starting from 0). Here I use master..spt_values instead. [SQL, Auxiliary table of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers)

```
select dateadd(day, N.Number, M.StartDate) as myDate,
       RequestType,
       Area, 
       count(*) as myCount
from mySPtable as M
  inner join master..spt_values as N
    on N.Number <= datediff(day, M.StartDate, M.EndDate)
where N.type = 'P'
group by dateadd(day, N.Number, M.StartDate),
         RequestType,
         Area
order by dateadd(day, N.Number, M.StartDate)
```

Comment: I found this very helpful for something related that I was stuck on!