# Get data for current month from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table setup as shown below.

Table Name: activity.

```
activity_id , Date       , assign_engr , Task_Type , Task_Status
1           , 2013-12-31 , Sachin      , Monthly   , Scheduled
2           , 2013-12-23 , Mikel       , Weekly    , Done
3           , 2013-10-18 , John        , Monthly   , Done
```

I want to get data for the current month only using Date field as shown below:

```
select * from activity where Date='current month'
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 6):

You may try like this:

```
select * from activity where MONTH(`Date`)=MONTH(NOW()) 
and YEAR(`Date`)=YEAR(NOW())
```

Comment: Thanks again for help. according my table can i get the day name of corresponding date using query. please help me.

Comment: @Basudev, to get the day name use `DATE_FORMAT(\`date\`,"%W")` look up http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp for other formats

Comment: @RahulTripathi you are genius thanks allot you save my time.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're storing dates in MySQL date format, so this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM activity
WHERE date_format(activity.`Date`, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m')
```

You need to restrict to year as well, I'm assuming at least; otherwise just checking the month value will get that month for all years.

Comment: Thanks; Rahul's answer was good, but just wanted to clarify that alternative to be safe. That way Basudev doesn't have to learn the hard way like the rest of us :P.

Answer (score -1):

Here is **index-friendly** alternative (assuming that `date` doesn't contain time components, meaning it's of type `DATE`)

```
SELECT *
  FROM activity
 WHERE date BETWEEN LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
                AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE())
```

**Note:**

1. Make sure that you have an index on `date` column
2. **Don't apply any functions (e.g. `MONTH()`, `YEAR()`...) to the column you're searching on** because it invalidates usage of any index(indices) you might have on it effectively causing a full scan on the table.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e02a/8)** demo

Comment: Sorry, no, not always going to work: `2013-02-28` - 1 Month: `2013-01-28` + 1 day: `2013-01-29`; off by 3 days (29th, 30th, 31st).  To get the start of the month, subtract the current day - 1.  You should also avoid the use of `BETWEEN`, in favor of an exclusive upper-bound (ie less than the start of the next month), which would allow the query to work irrespective of whether `date` has time components.  But yes, this basic approach allows indices to be used.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for the input :). Of course it should be +1day -1month. It was a typo. I was answering too late at night. Now the using of BETWEEN is a matter of preference as long as it's used without the time component.

Comment: ...And why not make this safe for that situation (with time components), which doesn't take that much more effort?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You've already made you point. I thought I said that before it's a matter of preference when applied appropriately. The whole point of my answer was about completely different and very important issue - getting index support. Now from what I see your answers are not so consistent on that point as one might think (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7112446/1920232, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10356338/1920232). But **again** thank you.