# Including a Where clause based on parameters in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Parameter called @Codes passing in an optional comma delimited string of system codes.

If this parameter has a value I want to filter the query with a

```
WHERE 
  blah = blah AND
  Code IN ('Code1','Code2','etc.')
```

If the parameter is null or empty I want to omit the last where filter entirely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WHERE 
  blah = blah AND
  (
  Code IN (SELECT TheItem FROM dbo.fnSplit(@Codes))
  OR
  @Codes IS NULL
  )
```

To change the CSV into a recordset, fee free to choose [one of the many functions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bsql-server%5D%20%2bfnsplit). Personally, I tend to the a [numbers table approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232)