# Is there a trick to use DISTINCT not only when SELECTING columns but also on the string contained in each entry?

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

I use

```
SELECT Distinct  [Material]  FROM Mytable
```

and get the following result:

```
Material
 --------------
 1469CDHKabef
 237BI
 237BI5
```

Is there way to filter this output further so that each letter that appears in the individual strings (row) only appears once?

Desired output is:

```
12345679BCDHKIabef
```

or even better, get the whole thing choped upp so that each letter/number ends up in a row of its own

Comment: Dint get your actual requirement in the question you have given. How you have ordered the "Desired output" while the result is of different order.

Comment: He wants to join the result in a single row and that to in sorted/ordered manner.

Comment: The order of the output does not matter to me, as long as each number/character only apears once in the output.In the original output I have 237BI twice. I only need each letter/number once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below uses master..spt_values as an adhoc auxiliary numbers table just for demonstration purposes. [You should create your own.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232)

```
WITH Numbers(N) AS
(
SELECT number
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type='P' AND number > 0
), Materials(Material) As
(
SELECT '1469CDHKabef' UNION ALL
SELECT '237BI' UNION ALL
SELECT '237BI5'
)
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Material,N,1)
FROM Materials
JOIN Numbers ON N <= LEN(Material)
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I guess I have some SQL studying to do ;-) Never heard of master..spt_values...

Comment: There's no particular reason you should have heard of it. It's just a system table that happens to be useful for this as it contains a sequential set of numbers from `0` to `2047` and is guaranteed to be present.