# Fastest way to add comma in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a long string stored in a table in SQL Server and I want to add a "comma" in between every 10 chars.

I did that with the help of while statement but it is so slow.

Is there any faster way to do that?

Here is what I did

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'


declare @i int = 1
declare @m int = 10
declare @ai varchar(max) = ''

while @i < len(@a)
begin
    set @ai = @ai + ',' + SUBSTRING(@a, @i, @m)
    set @i = @i + @m 
end

SELECT @ai
```

Working with a big table this method is too slow.

Is there any faster way?

Comment: It's hard to say which option is the fastest without trying out, but maybe this helps you, it's about the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595970/add-comma-every-nth-character-in-value

Comment: "is faster way to do that?" - yes. use a numbers table

Comment: @MitchWheat how is that?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a numbers table would be the best way to implement this.

You need to remember SQL Server is desiged to work with *sets of rows*. If you find yourself looping -always stop and think, could you approach the problem as a collection of rows?

The following implements a numbers table using a CTE (this would be a permanant table with rows from 1 up to whatever you need).

You can then select rows from the numbers table to match your requirements, in this case every 10th row using *modulo*, selecting the relevant substring portion. *string_agg* can then combine the rows back into a single string, automatically adding the comma separator.

The *stuff* function adds a comma to the beginning of the string like your own output produces, leave this off if that's not required.

```
declare @a varchar(max) = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890';

with n as (select top(Len(@a)) n = Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) from master.sys.objects)

select Stuff(String_Agg(Substring(@a,n, 10),',') within group (order by n),1,0,',')
from n
where (n-1) % 10 = 0 and n <= Len(@a);
```

**Performance comparison**

Using a suitably long string to test with (320k characters), the looping method takes over 3 seconds.

The same result using the numbers table implementation above takes about 94 milliseconds, so approximately 34x faster.

See this <kbd>[demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ece632adc66b114ba2b8dd7e0f784ecf)</kbd> with timings.

Comment: Would this not have troubles because of [What is MySQL row order for "SELECT * FROM table_name;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/what-is-mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name) ?  That question is about MySQL, but the reason also applied to MSSQL (or SQL in general).

Comment: @Luuk  Yes I should add an `order by n` for completeness, I have added above. It's correct that ordering in any resultset is not guaranteed unless specified. In practice selecting from a numbers table's clustered index should follow the table ordering unless things like multiple threads or fragmentation are a factor. Also saying that with the OPs specific example string would it matter as the string segments repeat - although alone not a reason to leave it out of course.

Comment: In this case, where all records contain `1234567890` it should not matter, But maybe the string in the real-life situation from OP does not follow this simplicity 

Comment: @Luuk Yes I have no doubt that is true; with the order by clause in the string_agg it is fine however, even the performance is also unnafected with a unique clustered index.

Answer (score 1):

by using accepted answer of  [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517816/t-sql-split-word-into-characters) and using `String_agg` and `NTILE functions`

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(max) = '123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890' 


 SELECT   String_agg( value, ',')
FROM     (
                  SELECT   String_agg( value, '') within GROUP ( ORDER BY nt1 ASC) value,
                           nt,
                           1 AS t
                  FROM    (
                                    SELECT   substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) value,
                                             ntile(18) OVER( ORDER BY (
                                                    SELECT NULL) ) nt,
                                             row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (
                                                    SELECT NULL) ) nt1
                                    FROM     (
                                                    SELECT @test b) a
                                    JOIN     master..spt_values v
                                    ON       v.number < len(a.b)
                                    WHERE    v.type = 'P') c
                  GROUP BY nt ) d
GROUP BY t
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=070f3276691dff0fa5c91f9fa74e38ef)