# SELECT lowest unused figure from range using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that has a 'location' field that ranges from 1 to 25. I use the  following SQL to currently return the lowest 'location' that is currently unused;

```
select top 1 field from [dbo].[misc_fields] where field NOT IN (select location from ListFields where listid = @listid) order by field
```

The problem with this is that it is reliant on the misc_fields table which contains a row for each location (1-25). I would like to remove the need to have this lookup table and just define the range within the Stored Procedure itself.

Comment: Please enter sample data, expected results, and what you currently have.  It is hard to tell what you are talking about.  We are not mind readers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taken from a link provided by Martin Smith;

```
 WITH Locations (Location) AS 
        ( 
         SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
         SELECT 1 + Location FROM Locations WHERE Location < 26 
        ) 

SELECT Location INTO #Locations FROM Locations 

SELECT TOP 1 Location from #Locations where Location NOT IN (select location from ListFields where listid = @listid) order by Location

DROP TABLE #Locations
```

Comment: Gotta love people marking down the accepted (therefore presumably working) answer well over 3 years after it was made, with no comments as to why.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I can think of right now, a bit more complex than what you have though;

```
SELECT MIN(pos) AS nextlocation FROM
(
  SELECT location, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY location) AS pos
  FROM ListFields WHERE listid=1
  UNION
  SELECT 0, MAX(location)+1
  FROM ListFields WHERE listid=1
) a
WHERE location<>pos;
```

Note that this isn't limited to 25, it may very well give out 26, so you'll need to detect your limit yourself elsewhere.

[SQLfiddle here to try it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cf87/1).

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't work. Serge.

try to use [IDENTITY function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx):

```
SELECT MIN(artificial_table.id) FROM your_table RIGHT JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 25 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS id) AS artificial_table 
ON your_table.id = artificial_table.id WHERE your_table.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The `IDENTITY` function is only useful for `SELECT ... INTO` not to create a standalone adhoc numbers table.

Comment: @Martin yes, I read the topic I pointed. Unfortunately I have no MSSQL to try, but I would give it a try.

Comment: @Martin, yes, it doesn't work (I found the link to SQLFiddle in the answer below)

Comment: Various ways of creating a numbers table on the fly [are discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232)