# Generate result set of a certain length

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to insert certain amount of rows into some table with values taken from variables. I certainly can do a loop inserting single row at a time, but that's too straightforward. I am looking for more elegant solution. My current thoughts are around `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement, but now I need a query that will generate the amount of rows that I need. I tried to write recursive CTE to do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ufGenerateRows(@numRows INT = 1)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE
(
    RowID INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH numbers AS
    (
        SELECT 1 as N
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N + 1
        FROM numbers 
        WHERE N + 1 <= @numRows
    )
    INSERT INTO @RtnValue
        SELECT N
        FROM numbers

    RETURN
END
GO
```

It works, but has a limit of recursion depth of 100, which is inappropriate for me. Can you suggest alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL, Auxiliary table of numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers)

Comment: You can set a `maxrecursion` limit greater than 100 but cross joined CTEs are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. always use the `dbo.` schema prefix when creating or referencing objects, *especially* functions.
2. you should strive to create inline table-valued functions, as opposed to multi-statement table-valued functions, when possible.
3. Recursive CTEs are about the least efficient way to generate a set (see this three-part series for much better examples):

   - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1
   - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2
   - http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Here is one example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateRows(@numRows INT = 1)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    SELECT TOP (@numRows) RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[number])
      FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS s1
      -- CROSS JOIN master.dbo.spt_values AS s2 
      ORDER BY s1.[number]
  );
```

If you need more than ~2,500 rows, you can cross join with itself, or another table.

Even better would be to create your own numbers table (again, see the links above for examples).

Answer (score 1):

Don't think iteratively - looping - but set-based - all at once.

An `INSERT INTO`...`SELECT TOP` *`x`*… should do what you need without repeated inserts.

I will follow with an example when I'm not bound to my phone.

UPDATE:

What @AaronBertrand said. :}  A `CROSS JOIN` in the `SELECT` is spot-on.

Comment: `SELECT` from what? In order to get top `@n` rows I need some source of rows that already has `@n` rows or more.