# How to remove lowercase letters from varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove the  lowercase letters from a varchar in a select.
Is it possible to do it without having to implement a function?

*Eg*:

```
 declare @s varchar(max) = 'ThisIsADifferentTest'
 select /*<some opperation with the varchar>*/@s
```

I want to obtain 'TIADT'

HINT: it would do if we could perform a boolean intersection between varchars:

```
select intersection(@s,UPPER(@s))
```

Comment: Just ASCII `a-z` or including accented / non English characters too?

Comment: just ASCII [a-z] would work

Comment: Of course I want to avoid to have twenty+ replaces.

Comment: Do you mean lowercase? Small Caps usually refers to `Cap`ital letters that are at a `Small`er size than normal.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my English is still clumsy (editing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best performing way would be to use CLR and regex. But you can use an auxiliary numbers table.

I use `spt_values` below for demo purposes. You should [create a permanent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232).

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(2047) = 'ThisIsADifferentTest';

WITH Nums
     AS (SELECT number
         FROM   master..spt_values
         WHERE  type = 'P'
                AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 2047)
SELECT CAST((SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, number, 1)
             FROM   Nums
             WHERE  number <= LEN(@s)
                    AND SUBSTRING(@s, number, 1) LIKE '[A-Z]' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin
             ORDER  BY number
             FOR XML PATH('')) AS VARCHAR(2047))
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2017+

```
declare @s varchar(max) = 'ThisIsADifferentTest'
 
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE (@s, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_+=!@#$%^&*()' COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin, REPLICATE(' ', 40)), ' ', '')
```