# List Lines per Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm probably over thinking this. I have a simple table with `Name` and `Ticket Quantity` columns. I want to output a row by row list of the names for each quantity purchased. See example below.

**Table:**

```
Name           Quantity
-----------------------
Bob            1
Joe            2
Sally          1
```

**Output:**

```
Bob
Joe
Joe
Sally
```

How could I achieve this in TSQL?

Comment: join onto a numbers table.

Comment: I smell a recursive CTE coming

Comment: @DanAndrews - [Recursive CTEs are slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232). Creating a permanent  numbers table and `SELECT Name FROM Names JOIN Numbers ON Number <= Quantity` would be better.

Comment: @MartinSmith Careful talking bad about CTEs.  They solve every problem ever conceived.

Comment: @cadrell0 you forgot to qualify that with, "... on SO"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SETUP:**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(10),
    Quantity INT
    )

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 'Bob',   1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Joe',   2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Sally', 1
```

**Recursive CTE**

```
;WITH Members (
    NAME,
    Quantity
    )
AS (
    -- Base case
    SELECT NAME,
        Quantity
    FROM @table

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive
    SELECT NAME,
        Members.Quantity - 1
    FROM Members
    WHERE Members.Quantity > 1
    )
SELECT NAME
FROM Members
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
ORDER BY 1
```

**Result:**

```
Bob
Joe
Joe
Sally
```

---

Alternatively you could (per @Martin Smith's suggestion):

```
DECLARE @numbers TABLE (number INT)

INSERT INTO @numbers (number)
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
```

**Finally:**

```
SELECT NAME
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN @numbers n ON n.number <= t.Quantity
ORDER BY 1
```

**Result:**

```
Bob
Joe
Joe
Sally
```

---

And if you really like recursive CTE's (because they smell good), you could build your numbers table with a recursive CTE.  You should be using physical tables and not variable tables as you see here - so that you don't have to build them every time.

```
;WITH Numbers (Value)
AS (
    -- Base case
    SELECT 32767 Value

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive
    SELECT Numbers.Value - 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Numbers.Value > 1
    )
INSERT INTO @numbers (number)
SELECT Value
FROM Numbers
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```