# SQL Current status for given day (FOR loop)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

For simplicity lets assume that I have a view with three fields

```
date_in (date)
Container (varchar)
date_out (date)
```

Now, the container is IN if the date_in is lesser or equal to given date and date_out is null or greater than given date. Now I am trying to count the containers for given time period. In pseudocode between two values STARTDATE and ENDDATE it would be something like

```
FOR X =STARTDATE, X<= ENDDADE, X++ {
if date_in <=X and date_out>x
count (container) 
}
```

or closer to SQL:

```
declare  @startdate date,
@d date;
set  @startdate = '1/01/2014'
set @d = @startdate
"FOR on the @d variable would go here" {



select @d as SNAP_DATE, count (container) where date_in <@d 
and (date_out is null or   date_out> @d)

}
```

It might be simple - I guess I could make a new table and manually do multiple SELECT INTO (and later query from this new table) but its not very elegant solution.

Edit: just to precise - in the end I'd like to have something like:

```
DATE      Count
1/02/2014   10
2/02/2014   15
 ...
7/03/2014   19
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this procedurally as follows:

1. Use a `while` loop to loop from start to end date.
2. Use a table variable to store each date-count pair.
3. Select from the table variable to get the summarised result.

   ```
   declare @start date = '1/01/2014'
   declare @end date = '7/03/2014'
   declare @tbl table(Date date, Count int)

   while(@start < @end)
    begin
     insert into @tbl
     select @start, count(*)
     from your_view
     where (in_date < @start) 
     and ((out_date is null) or (out_date > @start))

     set @start = dateadd(day, 1, @start)
    end

   select * from @tbl
   ```

Comment: Yes, but that would give me value for one day, I need for a whole period.

Comment: Would it help if you passed a second parameter and compared that with output date i.e. compare start of range with in date and end with out date?

Comment: Not really sure what you mean: In SQL I have 
Declare  startdate date D date;
set  startdate = '1/01/2014' set d=startdate
select d, count (container) from VIEW where date_in<= d and time_out....  Now I have to keep changing the @D in the FOR loop somehow

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like the following.  It uses a numbers table, which can be a real or derived table.  It contains rows of integers.  You need a table that begins with 0 and has enough values to cover your date range.  Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) for more information on a numbers table.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '1/2/2014'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '1/4/2014'

SELECT DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate) AS DATE, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM Numbers n
JOIN MyView mv ON mv.date_in < DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate)
    AND (mv.date_out IS NULL OR mv.date_out > DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate))
WHERE DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate)
ORDER BY DATEADD(d, n.num, @StartDate)
```

The numbers in the numbers table are converted to the list of dates between the date range.  Each date is joined to your view based on the criteria you need.