# Repeat Rows N Times According to Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, repeat

I have following table.

```
Table A:
ID         ProductFK         Quantity       Price
------------------------------------------------
10         1                  2           100
11         2                  3           150
12         1                  1           120
----------------------------------------------
```

I need select that repeat Rows N Time According to Quantity Column Value.

So I need following select result:

```
ID        ProductFK         Quantity        Price
------------------------------------------------
10        1                   1          100
10        1                   1          100
11        2                   1          150
11        2                   1          150
11        2                   1          150
12        1                   1          120
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do that with a recursive CTE using `UNION ALL`:

```
;WITH cte AS
  (
    SELECT * FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.[ID], cte.ProductFK, (cte.[Order] - 1) [Order], cte.Price
    FROM cte INNER JOIN Table1 t
      ON cte.[ID] = t.[ID]
    WHERE cte.[Order] > 1
)
SELECT [ID], ProductFK, 1 [Order], Price
FROM cte
ORDER BY 1
```

Here's a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0f383/7).

[Here's a longer explanation of this technique](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

---

Since your input is too large for this recursion, you could use an auxillary table to have "many" dummy rows and then use `SELECT TOP([Order])` for each input row (`CROSS APPLY`):

```
;WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
      E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b),
      E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b),
      E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b),
      E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b)
SELECT t.[ID], t.ProductFK, 1 [Order], t.Price
FROM Table1 t CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP(t.[Order]) N
  FROM E16) ca
ORDER BY 1
```

(The auxillary table is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers), it allows up to 65536 rows per input row and can be extended if required)

Here's a working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b2cb3/1).

Comment: I get this error:    The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Comment: what's the maximum `[Order]` value you have?

Comment: could implement with Cross Apply ?

Comment: @franchescototti: Use [option maxrecursion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: @cha - `maxrecursion` won't help here. recursion end when it's no longer needed in the first solution. limiting to any lower bound won't result in the required output

Comment: @cha - ohhh... you mean `MAXRECURSION 0`... Yes, that's a valid option.

Comment: Is there a mysql solution to it? It looks like if we use MySQL the above method will not work.

Answer (score 45):

You can use a simple `JOIN` to get the desired result as below:

```
SELECT  t1.*, t2.number + 1 RepeatNumber
FROM    TableA t1
JOIN    master.dbo.spt_values t2 ON t2.type = 'P' AND t2.number < t1.Quantity
```

The above query repeats each record by the specified number in `Quantity` column.

**Note for `master.dbo.spt_values on type = 'P'`:**

This table is used for getting a series of number which is hard-coded in it by
 condition of `type = 'P'`.

Comment: Works wonderful, simple and clear. 
Little edit **master.dbo.spt_values t2 on t2.type = 'P' and t2.number < t1.Quantity**

Comment: The problem here is that it just works for under 2048 records. :(

Comment: @Barsham, You're right. but this is a simple answer for small domain. If you need more than 2048 records, you must use some other ways such as `Recursive CTE` or `CROSS JOIN` with `master.dbo.spt_values` in order to get larger values.

Comment: Thanks @SiyavashHamdi for your comment. I end up using JOIN with an existing table with 1 million sequental records which was in my system and performance was more align with my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The `generate_series` keyword might be used:

```
Select ID,ProductFK,1 as Quantity, Price from TableA t cross join generate_series(1,t.Quantity);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

considering this table called prep:

[image: prep]

and by making use of the `table(sequence())` function (available in trino)
you can make a temp table with n numbers, join <= that on your initial Quantity column

```
select 1 as new_quantity, action, user 
from (
    select * 
    from prep
    
) t1

left join (
    
    select sequential_number
    from table(sequence(1,1000))

) t2
on t2.sequential_number <= t1.quantity
```

if you need a range from 0 to n (as i did), then simply select the sequential_number column.

Answer (score -5):

```
CREATE TAblE #temp
(
T_Name      VARCHAR(50),
T_Times      BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO #temp(T_Name,T_Times) VALUES ('ASHISH',4)
INSERT INTO #temp(T_Name,T_Times) VALUES ('PANKAJ',3)
INSERT INTO #temp(T_Name,T_Times) VALUES ('RUPESH',2)
INSERT INTO #temp(T_Name,T_Times) VALUES ('MANISH',5)

SELECT t.T_Name ,t.T_Times FROM
(SELECT  T_Name,T_Times,CAST(('<val>'+REPLICATE(T_Name+'</val><val>',T_Times-1)
+'</val>') AS XML )AS X FROM #temp)t CROSS APPLY t.X.nodes('/val')y(z)

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Keep your answers self contained please! Frequently referring to your blog site is close to spamming, and not really considered useful at Stack Overflow.