# Creating sequence in SQL with different length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the customer identifier as PK and his time to maturity in months:

```
Customer |  Maturity
---------+-----------
1             80
2             60
3             52
4             105
```

I want to create a table which will have customer identifier and the maturity will be defined as sequence of number with the increment + 1:

```
Customer |  Maturity
---------+------------
1             1
1             2
1            ....
1             80
2             1
2             2
2            ...
2             60
```

I don't know whether I should use a sequence or the cross join or how to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat Rows N Times According to Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327837/repeat-rows-n-times-according-to-column-value)

Answer (score 2):

You can try joining your current table to a sequence table to generate the maturity ranges you want.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS seq
    UNION ALL
    SELECT seq + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE seq < 500
)

SELECT
    t1.Customer,
    t2.seq AS Maturity
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.seq <= t1.Maturity
ORDER BY
    t1.Customer,
    t2.seq
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 2):

one way is to use recursive CTE.

```
; with cte as
(
    select  Customer, M = 1, Maturity
    from    yourtable
    union all
    select  Customer, M = M + 1, Maturity
    from    yourtable
    where   M < Maturity
)
select  *
from    cte
option (MAXRECURSION  0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try query like below

```
create table t (Customer int,  Maturity int)
insert into t values 
(1,80)
,(2,60)
,(3,52)
,(4,105);

select Customer, r from 
t cross join
(select top (select max(maturity) from t)
row_number() over( order by (select NULL)) r 
from sys.objects s1 cross join sys.objects s2) k
where r<=Maturity
order by Customer asc,r asc
```

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/JOVOD25734)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below.
Created two temporary tables to represent your tables in below example.
You need to replace them with you table names and drop the first three lines.

```
declare @Customer table (Customer int, Maturity int)
declare @NewTable table (Customer int, Maturity int)
insert @Customer select 1, 80

declare @x int = 0
declare @iterations table (x int)
while @x <= (select max(Maturity) from @Customer)
begin
    set @x += 1
    insert @iterations select @x
end

insert @NewTable
select  c.Customer, i.x from @Customer c left join @iterations i on i.x <= c.Maturity

select * from @NewTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Late answer**, but another option is an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.customer 
      ,Maturity = B.N
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Top (A.Maturity) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                  From master..spt_values n1
             ) B
```

Comment: i like your answer best,becasue your r using simple number table and if number table is permanent then query is more simple.

Comment: @KumarHarsh actually any table of appropriate size will do.  spt_values has 2,500 records.  If you need more, you can use master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2  which has up to 6,365,529 records