# Select sequential numbers as rows to serve as inputs to a user defined function

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, row-number

I has a scalar valued function that takes an integer as one of it's input. I need a query that runs that function for the set of integers `(1,2,3,4,5)`. This is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT dbo.MyFunction('2016-05-13', Number) 
FROM (SELECT TOP 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Number FROM SomeTable) AS T
```

And this works. Is there a way I can do it without the `FROM SomeTable` since I don't actually use any information contained in the table?

Alternatively, is there a cleaner way to write the entire query?

Comment: It should be noted that your current query is ill-defined, in that if `SomeTable` contains more than 5 rows, there was *no* guarantee that you would, in fact, retrieve 5 rows with the numbers 1-5.

Comment: Perhaps rethinking this process would be a better approach. Instead of using a scalar function (which are horribly inefficient), you could rethink this to be an inline table valued function that uses a tally table. It would be faster and more flexible than calling a scalar function over and over. If you can share the content of your function I will put something together to demonstrate.

Comment: @SeanLange performance isn't really an issue here, I just need to pull these values into a spreadsheet once a day. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2008, we have [table value constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
SELECT dbo.MyFunction('2016-05-13', Number) 
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) AS T(Number)
```

If "5" is an arbitrary number and you need this to run over any sequential sequence, you will still need to use a `nums` table of some sort. Rather than repeat the various techniques for that here, I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers) and its answers.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Apologies for this add-on question, but if I want to use the result of `dbo.MyFunction` in a `WHERE` clause, do I need to nest that in an outer query?

Comment: If you really want to use the results in a `WHERE`, for starters, use an inline table-valued function. Scalar functions have atrocious performance. As an added bonus, when you `CROSS APPLY` those they result in a column that's easily filtered in a `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks, so even if the function is only ever going to return a single value, I should still make it a table-valued function rather than a scalar-value one? Is there any advantage / point to scalar-values functions then?

Comment: They're simpler to write -- but unfortunately, that's about it, as long as the optimizer isn't overhauled. Fortunately, things are looking up for [in-memory OLTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn935012), where they are actually fast.

Comment: One caveat I would add is that the performance benefit is almost always worse if your table valued function is a multi-statement table valued function. That means if there is more than a single select statement in the body. What happens in that case is it will be treated like a scalar function and the optimizer get confused and the performance is horrible.