# SQL Server: How do I get the highest value not set of an int column?

Tags: sql-server

Let's take an example. These are the rows of the table I want get the data:

[image]

The column I'm talking about is the `reference` one. The user can set this value on the web form, but the system I'm developing must suggest the lowest `reference` value still not used.

As you can see, the smallest value of this column is 35. I could just take the smaller reference and sum 1, but, in that case, the value 36 is already used. So, the value I want is 37.

Is there a way to do this without a loop verification? This table will grow so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for 2012+

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (id int, reference int)
INSERT INTO @Tbl
        ( id, reference )
VALUES  
(1, 49),
(2, 125),
(3, 35),
(4, 1345),
(5, 36),
(6, 37)


SELECT
    MIN(A.reference) + 1 Result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD(reference) OVER (ORDER BY reference) Tmp
    FROM
        @Tbl
) A
WHERE
    A.reference - A.Tmp != -1
```

Result: 37

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another place where the tally table is going to prove invaluable. In fact it is so useful I keep a view on my system that looks like this.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a cross join E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a cross join E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Next of course we need some sample data and table to hold it.

```
create table #Something
(
    id int identity
    , reference int
    , description varchar(10)
)

insert #Something (reference, description)
values (49, 'data1')
    , (125, 'data2')
    , (35, 'data3')
    , (1345, 'data4')
    , (36, 'data5')
    , (7784, 'data6')
```

Now comes the magic of the tally table.

```
select top 1 t.N
from cteTally t
left join  #Something s on t.N = s.reference
where t.N >= (select MIN(reference) from #Something)
    and s.id is null
order by t.N
```

Comment: Your tally table appears to be using an older style join syntax.  Is that for brevity?

Comment: @datagod yes it is for brevity. And as much as I suggest to others to not use that I shouldn't be doing it myself. In this case I truly do want a cross join so I should explicitly state it as such. I will update this momentarily.

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly, but should get the job done:

```
select
  top 1 reference+1
from
  [table]
where
  reference+1 not in (select reference from [table])
order by reference
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a table valued express to get the next value.   I first left outer joined the table to itself (shifting the key in the join by +1).  I then looked only at rows that had no corresponding match (b.ID is null).  The minimum a.ReferenceID + 1 gives us the answer we are looking for.

```
create table MyTable
( 
  ID int identity,
  Reference int,
  Description varchar(20)
)

insert into MyTable values (10,'Data')
insert into MyTable values (11,'Data')
insert into MyTable values (12,'Data')
insert into MyTable values (15,'Data')

-- Find gap
;with Gaps as
(
  select a.Reference+1 as 'GapID'
    from MyTable a
    left join MyTable b on a.Reference = b.Reference-1
    where b.ID is null
)
select min(GapID) as 'NewReference'
  from Gaps

NewReference
------------
13
```

I hope the code was clearer than my description.

Comment: While this will work it is actually a hidden row by agonizing row type of solution. When you use a recursive cte joined to itself like this it is the same thing as using a rcte for counting. Check out this article which goes into detail about the performance problems with this type of thing. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: @SeanLange, this is not a recursive CTE though.  I am not saying this is uber efficient, but I don't think it is agonizing.

Comment: I will say though that with 1,000,000 records and a gap at the 50,000 record mark, my solution took 3828 reads.  Not acceptable at all.

Comment: Oops...when I saw this it looked like an rcte...I really need to pay more attention. :D The self join as you found out works really well up to a point and then it kind of deterioriates.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #T(ID INT , REFERENCE INT, [DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #T

SELECT 1,49  , 'data1'  UNION ALL
SELECT 2,125 , 'data2'  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,35  , 'data3'  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1345, 'data4'  UNION ALL
SELECT 5,36  , 'data5'  UNION ALL
SELECT 6,7784, 'data6'  

SELECT TOP 1 REFERENCE + 1
FROM #T T1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM #T T2 WHERE T2.REFERENCE = T1.REFERENCE + 1 
)
ORDER BY T1.REFERENCE

--- OR 

SELECT MIN(REFERENCE) + 1
FROM #T T1
WHERE
NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM #T T2 WHERE T2.REFERENCE = T1.REFERENCE + 1 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a Tally table. The following illustrates the concept. It would be better to use a persisted numbers table as opposed to the cte however the code below illustrates the concept.

For further reading as to why you should use a persisted table, check out the following link: [sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers)

```
DECLARE @START int = 1, @END int = 1000

CREATE TABLE #TEST(UsedValues INT)
INSERT INTO #TEST(UsedValues) VALUES
(1),(3),(5),(7),(9),(11),(13),(15),(17)

;With NumberSequence( Number ) as
(
    Select @start as Number
        union all
    Select Number + 1
        from NumberSequence
        where Number < @end
)

SELECT MIN(Number)
FROM NumberSequence n
LEFT JOIN #TEST t
    ON n.Number = t.UsedValues
WHERE UsedValues IS NULL
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 1000 )
```

Comment: If you read that entire answer you linked it explains that using the recursive cte like you did here is horrible for performance.

Comment: You are correct and that is why I highlighted the fact. The best way would be to use a persisted tally table instead.

Answer (score -2):

You could try using a descending order:

```
SELECT DISTINCT reference
FROM `Resultsados`
ORDER BY `reference` ASC;
```

As far as I know, there is no way to do this without a loop. To prevent multiple values from returning be sure to use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: How would that help him find 37? That would find 7784, and all the other lesser values in order, but it wouldn't show which values are *un*used.

Comment: Oh, I guess it should be `ASC`.

Comment: How does the ASC help? This returns all values where as the OP wants a single, unused value