# insert multiple records into table based on values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `basetable` as given below

```
id name qty price
2  a    2    20
3  d    3    10
4  b    5    60
```

i want to insert the record into another table based on quantity,As given in able table id 2 has two quantity so table2 will contain 2 records for it with modified quantity as 1.

I tried it using while loop & insert statement and it worked but I want to achieve it using select into statement.

Answer (score 4):

**Sidebar Recommendation Concerning rCTEs that Increment a Count**

We'll get to the problem in just a minute but here's a recommendation for future code.

As slick as they may seem, you should avoid Recursive CTEs (rCTEs) that increment a count because they're actually slower than a well formed While loop and use a ton more resources even for small row counts.  Apologies for not doing a write up here on that subject but it would take a very long post to explain/demonstrate the reasons why. If you're interested on knowing more about the problems with rCTEs that count, there's an article on the subject that you could have a look at. I believe that site below has now made it so you can view articles without being a member.

[Hidden RBAR: Counting with Recursive CTE's](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/)

(If you want a StackOverflow link, try this one. It has a test you can actually run along with results from my humble box. [SQL, Auxiliary table of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers/2663232#2663232)  ).

Here's one of the performance charts from that article.  If you look at the Red, almost vertical skyrocket of a line on the far left, that's the performance curve of an rCTE.  It's really bad.

[image: Performance Comparison of rCTEs vs. 3 Other Common Methods]

**Readily Consumable Test Data for the Posted Problem**

Getting back to the problem at hand, here's some readily consumable test data that others can use and play with.  It's a little bit more than the original just to demonstrate the capabilities.

```
--===============================================================================
--      Create a test table for the original problem.
--      This is NOT a part of the solution.
--      We're just creating a larger set of data to test with.
--===============================================================================
--===== If the test table exists, drop it to make reruns in SSMS easier.
     -- We'll use a Temp Table just to prevent accidental drops of a real table.
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTable','U') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #TestTable
;
GO --Just to make table modifications easier if the table already exists.
--===== Create and populate the test table on-the-fly (kept this 2005 compatible)
   WITH cteTestData (SomeID,SomeName,Qty,Price) AS
        (
         SELECT 4,'D',5,60 UNION ALL --Need to make 5 rows.
         SELECT 2,'B',4,20 UNION ALL --Need to make 4 rows.
         SELECT 5,'F',0,86 UNION ALL --Need to make 0 rows.
         SELECT 3,'C',2,10 UNION ALL --Need to make 2 rows.
         SELECT 1,'D',2,22 UNION ALL --Need to make 2 rows. Name duplicated.
         SELECT 7,'D',1,11           --Need to make 1 row.  Name duplicated.
        )
 SELECT SomeID,SomeName,Qty,Price
   INTO #TestTable
   FROM cteTestData
;
--===== Display the contents of the table in order by name and quantity 
     -- just to make verification easy.
 SELECT *
   FROM #TestTable
  ORDER BY SomeName,Qty
;
GO
```

**Building a Useful Tool - fnTally**

We could solve this totally inline but we might as well add a very useful tool to our T-SQL server toolbox.  This one is a simplified Tally Table - like function that simply counts from 1 to the parameterized max.  It's an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function) which means that, unlike scalar or multi-statement functions, is nasty fast and produces zero logical reads (thank you Mr. Ben-Gan) in the process. It uses cCTEs (Cascading CTEs) based on CROSS JOINs to make it so fast rather than any form of recursion.  That also means that you don't have to set the MAXRCURSION option anywhere.  You'll find dozens of uses for a function like this in the future.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Return a column of BIGINTs from 1up to and including @MaxN with a max value of 1 Trillion.

 As a performance note, it takes about 00:01:45 (hh:mm:ss) to generate 1 Billion numbers to a throw-away variable.

 Usage:
--===== Basic syntax example (Returns BIGINT)
 SELECT t.N
   FROM dbo.fnTally(@MaxN) t
;

 Notes:
 1. Can also be used with APPLY.
 2. Note that this does not contain Recursive CTEs (rCTE), which are much slower and resource intensive.
 3. Based on Itzik Ben-Gan's cascading CTE (cCTE) method for creating a "readless" Tally Table source of BIGINTs.
    Refer to the following URLs for how it works and introduction for how it replaces certain loops. 
    http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/
    http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/virtual-auxiliary-table-numbers
 4. As a bit of a sidebar, one of the definitions of the word "Tally" is "to count", which is what this function does.
    It "counts" from 1 to whatever the value of @MaxN is every time it's called and it does so without producing any
    logical reans and it's nasty fast.
 5. I don't normally use the "Hungarian Notation" method of naming but I also have a table name Tally and so this 
    function needed to be named differently.

-- Jeff Moden
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  E1(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL --Could be converted to VALUES after 2008
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL --but there's no performance gain in doing so
            SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL --so kept it "2005 compatible".
            SELECT 1)                               --10^1 or 10 rows
, E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b, E1 c, E1 d)   --10^4 or 10 Thousand rows
,E12(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b, E4 c)         --10^12 or 1 Trillion rows (yeah, call me when that's done. ;-)                 
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN) N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E12 -- Values from 1 to @MaxN
;
GO
```

**Solution is Now Easy, Short, and Nasty Fast**

Once you have such a function in place, solutions to this type of problem (relational multiplication) become super easy and nearly trivial.  Here's a very high performance solution to the problem given using the test data I provided above.

```
    --===== Solve the original problem
     SELECT  st.SomeID
            ,st.SomeName
            ,Qty = 1
            ,st.Price --Assuming Price is "for each".
       FROM #TestTable st
      CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally(st.Qty)
      ORDER BY SomeName,SomeID --Not necessary. Just makes visual verification easy.
;
```

Here's the result set from that.

```
SomeID      SomeName Qty         Price
----------- -------- ----------- -----------
2           B        1           20
2           B        1           20
2           B        1           20
2           B        1           20
3           C        1           10
3           C        1           10
1           D        1           22
1           D        1           22
4           D        1           60
4           D        1           60
4           D        1           60
4           D        1           60
4           D        1           60
7           D        1           11

(14 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE to generate the data:

```
with cte as (
      select bt.id, bt.name, bt.qty, bt.price, 1 as cnt
      from basetable bt
      union all
      select bt.id, bt.name, bt.qty, bt.price, cnt + 1
      from cte
      where cnt < bt.qty
     )
select id, name, 1 as qty, price
from cte;
```

If you want to put the data in another table, then either use an `insert` before the `select` or an `into` after the `select`.

Note:  If your quantities get really big, you might have to investigate the `MAXRECURSION` option.

Comment: Thanks @gordon Linoff but it shows the error on select statement which is written immediate after union all. Error is "The multi-part identifier "bt.qty" could not be bound." this error appears for each column mentioned in query

Comment: quantity is not much big its will be  max to max 2K

Comment: it works i have changed the bt to another parameter for cte table and in where condition i checked it in cte table only

Comment: This solution does not work it quantity is more than 101

Comment: @Pavan . . . Then you need to use the `MAXRECURSION` option, as stated in the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If qty is going to be 2000 (max) for each product (row) then maxrecursion option won't work as max number of rows has not been mentioned.

Comment: @Coder1991 . . . The number of recursive steps is based only on the maximum value of `qty`, not on the maximum number of rows.