# How to find Missing number in Sequence field using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table called `Student` and field name called `StudentNumber`

**Student** Table

```
StudentNumber
-------------
 1
 2 
 3
 4
 5
 8
 10
```

**Expecting output**

```
6
7
9
```

I tried like below

```
Declare @trans int;
set @trans = 1;

while(@trans <=50000)
BEGIN
    if((select StudentNumber from [Student] where StudentNumber = @trans) != @trans)
    BEGIN
        print @trans;
    END
END

set @trans = @trans + 1;
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @jhen I tried like above

Comment: maybe loop till the max(number) and check on each iteration if the id exists or not ?

Comment: is the number 50000 fixed all the time? or might be changed?

Comment: @monah I am looking for missing number less than 50000

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

```
declare @id int
declare @maxStudentNumber int

set @id = 1
select @maxStudentNumber = max(StudentNumber) from Student

create table #MissingIds
(
    id int
)

while @id < @maxStudentNumber
begin
    insert into #MissingIds values(@id)
    set @id = @id + 1
end

select m.id 
from #MissingIds m 
left join Student s 
on m.id = s.StudentNumber 
where s.StudentNumber is null

drop table #MissingIds
```

Comment: It will not be null. there is no number

Comment: @Liamneesan In the case of a `LEFT JOIN`, if there is no matching row in the right-hand table, you get a `NULL` value back for all columns from the right-hand table. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: What do you mean exactly "It will not be null" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use (SQL Server 2016 and above):

```
SELECT Number
FROM (select cast([key] as int) + 
      (SELECT MIN(StudentNumber) FROM Students) as number 
      from OPENJSON( '[1' 
      + replicate(',1',(SELECT MAX(StudentNumber) FROM Students)-
                       (SELECT MIN(StudentNumber) FROM Students))+']')) n
LEFT JOIN Students s
  ON n.number = s.StudentNumber
WHERE s.StudentNumber IS NULL;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=778c77f88485eb83a62d839987085bf9)**

Note: You could exchange first subquery with any other tally number generator.
More info: [SQL, Auxiliary table of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819/sql-auxiliary-table-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

it should be like below

```
Declare @trans int;
set @trans = 1;

while(@trans <=50000)
BEGIN
if NOT EXISTS (select StudentNumber from [Student] where StudentNumber = @trans)
BEGIN
    print @trans;
END
END

set @trans = @trans + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
;with report as(
   select 1 as missing
   union all
   select missing + 1
   from report
   where missing < @max
)


select *
from report m
where not exists ( select 1 from student s where s.id = m.missing)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Here a working [demo](http://rextester.com/GNHY40523)

Result

```
  missing
    6
    7
    9
```

Hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

I know you try to solve it iterative, just for sports
an idea how to achieve the same using recursive CTE

```
with missingstudents (StudentNumber)
as (
  select StudentNumber-1 from Students s 
     where not exists (
       select StudentNumber from Students s2 
          where s.StudentNumber-1 = s2.StudentNumber)
UNION ALL
  select StudentNumber-1 from missingstudents s 
     where not exists (
       select StudentNumber from Students s2 
          where s.StudentNumber-1 = s2.StudentNumber)
)
select * from missingstudents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select m.number from 
(select min(StudentNumber) a,max(StudentNumber) b from Students) c ,master..spt_values M
where c.a <= m.number
and c.b > = m.number
and type ='P'
and m.number not in (select StudentNumber from Students)
```